# Should I flag answers which are copied from an exact duplicate question?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-answers

I recently see [How to add the list elements in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22535965/how-to-add-the-list-elements-in-python) and in a few minutes it received *close-as-duplicate* votes, and I am the last one to vote and close the question.

The question already have some answers with [one of them have some upvotes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22536150/257972), When I check the answers of the the duplicate question, I saw that related user just copied the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14917111/257972) and send it as an answer.

*Copy-pasted answer is as follows:*
[image]

Should I flag the answer? If yes which flag should I use?

Comment: Author already deleted his stolen answer. :/

Comment: I comment to say *he better mark the question as duplicate instead of copy-pasting the accepted answer* and down-voted. After me, He received some more down-votes. Can 10+K see the deleted answer?

Comment: Sure, here is a screenshot for all to see: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Meo5z.png :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard can I put that image to my question since users with <10K rep could not see deleted answer.

Comment: Sure, go ahead - think it will make your point clearer.

Comment: This post should not be related *only* with duplicate questions. I saw **many** answers ([here's the last](http://i.stack.imgur.com/OnFqk.png)) by low-rep which are copied (**exactly** as the original) from [the accepted answer](http://i.stack.imgur.com/a0TvO.png) on [the same page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209814/posting-toast-message-from-a-thread). And this after 4 years... Woah!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can make an argument for plagiarizing another answer here.  Use a custom flag and say that it is copying another answer from the duplicate question (provide a link) without attribution.

Comment: only if the duplicate answer ist not refferenced right?

Comment: @AndreschSerj Due to the complexity involved in discussing plagiarism and related issues, trying to exhaustively cover the general case isn't really feasible.  I'm just discussing this specific case here.

Comment: I'd suggest that as a general rule, if copying significant chunks from another users' answer, attribution is never a bad thing.