# Dealing with answers which just link to "possible duplicate" and copy a snippet from it

Tags: discussion, specific-answer, low-quality-posts

I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8412360/google-maps-change-from-satellite-view-to-street-view/8412437#8412437) which contained the following:

> See this [possible
>   duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6471792/236732)
>
> ```
>      mapView.setStreetView(true);
>      mapView.setSatellite(false);
>      mapView.invalidate();
> ```

The code in the answer is just a little bit of the copied code from the duplicate question.

This is related to [Should I flag answers which are copied from an exact duplicate question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251021/should-i-flag-answers-which-are-copied-from-an-exact-duplicate-question), however in this case they have technically provided attribution, unlike the example given in the other post. What should be done about these posts?

Comment: vote to close the question

Comment: In my opinion , duplicate is duplicate. And the questions should be flag as duplicate if it's really duplicate. For the answer. If it is correct , just leave it.