# Exact copies of an answer should be punished

Tags: discussion, duplicate-answers, plagiarism

I was having some fun on Data Exchange and wanted to see if many people would post [Exact duplicate answers on several questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/198440/exact-duplicate-answers-per-user). Now obviously they do, even a lot of high reputation users.

Shouldn't this behaviour be punished in some way? If you know that you provided an answer to a question before and even took the time to find it, copy the answer, and then post it again as an answer, I believe that you are just hunting for rep.

If you can post an exact copy of your answer, then I guess in 99% of the cases the question should have been closed as duplicate.

Now I found [Should I flag answers which are copied from an exact duplicate question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251021/434949) which is even more evil, because it's not even your own answer, but I'm not sure if I should flag somebody for "He knew it was duplicate, but didn't do anything."

Comment: What type of punishment are you suggesting?  If users post similar answers in a short amount of time, then a flag is automatically generated.

Comment: @bluefeet: It doesn't even have to be a short amount of time I think.

Comment: @BoltClock ah ok, I've been trying to find a MSE/MSO post that might say the timeframe needed to generate this flag but I've not found one.

Comment: @bluefeet I believe the OP means if you copy an answer of your own from an older post and paste it as an answer to a new, similar question instead of VTC as dupe

Comment: @codeMagic Yes, I got that.  When the same user posts the same answer to multiple posts it generates a [flag automatically](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160134/how-should-one-respond-to-duplicate-answer-flags) called duplicate answers so this is already being raised for review.

Comment: Ah, good to know. Thanks! I don't think he just wants them reviewed but "punished". Maybe with fire or something...not really sure.

Comment: 50 push-ups or a lap around SO server park might do?

Comment: There's a "punishment" on code-only questions. So people just add some useless text and we end up with a code-only + nonsense question. Your proposed penalty will produce duplicate + nonsense answers.

Comment: If someone copies someone else's work and presents it as their own then that's bad.  But to copy ones own post seems to me to be at least marginally acceptable.  There are worse problems here to get your shorts in a knot about.

Comment: Looking at the first two sets in your list, the second is legitimate, more or less -- the user had asked several related questions about problems he was having and they all turned out to be due to the same issue.  The first set was someone responding to old threads and is probably a case of someone "mining" points, but his bigger crime is creating so many "zombie" threads -- now *there's* something I'd like to see punished somehow.

Comment: Some of the duplicate answers are egregious copying — even at least one case of plagiarism (two users, verbatim the same answer).  Some cases — Google drive problems — could reasonably be given the same answer "It was a (real) glitch but is now fixed".

Comment: My own personnal suggestion, is that 50 push-ups or a lap around SO server park might do....
I'll start.

Comment: Your assumption that duplicating answers is hunting for rep is rather insulting.  I've been duplicating answers for some time (usually not more than thrice, though), only because I don't care about duplicate questions as long as they have the right answer, each time wondering if it was bad practice or not, and each time giving up before I could find an answer until I decided today to do an extensive search and found this very question after a bit of struggling.  So if the policy is to avoid duplicate answers, please *make it obvious*, e.g. add it to the FAQ, please.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Whenever someone is posting the same answer to multiple questions an automatic moderator flag is raised.  No automatic *action* is taken because it's not always clear what that action should be, so it is left at just a flag.

If the questions are duplicates, the moderator can close them accordingly.

If the answers aren't suitable for the questions, they can be deleted and the author notified of what they did wrong.

If the answers are spam/advertising (which is often the case) the appropriate actions can be taken.

Comment: If that's true then why are there so many exact duplicates?  That query shows thousands for this year so far.

Comment: Probably the answers are not completely unsuitable but rather need some editing to adapt to the specific question and that is not done, neither by the answerer nor by the moderator. That's why many exact duplicate answers remain on SO.

Comment: @Trilarion, More probably, the answers are duplicates because the questions are duplicates that weren't closed in time. For example [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22887350/331508) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22332007/331508).

Comment: @BrockAdams That would even be spam in my eyes. An exact copy to use an external library that is owned by the user.

Comment: @HugoDelsing, yeah it almost looks like spam but that same answer was posted several times and not deleted as spam yet (that we can see).  Some self promotion is allowed in posts and that guy seems to be doing it right (except for the duplicates part).

Comment: @BrockAdams I don't know about "doing it right". He is adding a disclaimer, but does that really give him a pass to spam this site with free advertising? StackOverflow SELLS ads....

Comment: @Chris As long as the posts *answer the question asked*, any affiliations are included in a disclaimer, and the accounts sole purpose is not to post answers requiring the use of their product, it's fine.  Users are not globally prohibited form posting answers that utilize products, nor are they prohibited from posting answers for products they are affiliated with.

Comment: @Servy In the example Brock posted, [30 posts, 21 contain a link to the product](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1034153+wurfl.io). I've posted about this myself, and I am still not clear where the line is supposed to be. The example account not only copy/pastes the same advertisement on every post, it looks, to me, like the purpose of the account is to market that product. However, I note that no administrative action has been taken. It makes me question the wisdom in my free participation here -- I could monetize my activity just as easily as they have.

Comment: @BrockAdams Interestingly, I wouldn't have closed those questions as duplicates.  There's a difference between detecting a mobile device (as in the older question) and a tablet (as in the newer question): the one looking to identify a tablet is asking a more specific question.  Note that only some of the answers in the original question are applicable to the newer question.  If a question is really a duplicate, IMO, *all* valid answers to the original should be also be valid answers to the newer question.

Comment: @Jules, Duplicate does not mean carbon copy, and the difference you cite is trivial. Further **the accepted answer just points back to the duplicate question** and generically recommends modernizr. You can't get much more duplicate than that.

Answer (score 8):

If an answer applies to multiple questions, then that's usually when the questions are duplicates. If they *are* actually duplicates, vote to close as such (with the best question as the close-target).

If the user is blindly reposting the same answer on different *unrelated* questions, then the correct course of action would be to flag them for moderator attention with a custom message, explaining the situation (and optionally linking to the other answers you've found).

In any case, posting the same answer to multiple questions is **not acceptable**. But I don't think they should be "punished". Flag those answers - they will be deleted and the poster will lose all the reputation they gained from it. If the user repeats the same behavior even after the deletions, they may get suspended. I believe that is punishment enough.

Now, on the other hand, if an answer is an exact copy of an answer (without attribution) by a *different* author, that's plagiarism. It is strictly frowned upon. These kind of answers should also be flagged for moderator attention with a message like: "Plagiarized from <link to answer>" — the moderators will then review them and delete them if necessary.

Comment: What about answers that are to unrelated questions, but are still valid and apply? Say a question  about deprecated behaviour, and an answer encouraging to move on to modern, supported way of doing things (with proper links and background info to back that up and telling how to do so)? ([example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22377672/365237))

Comment: @eis: You can still add some commentary or example that is specific to the question.  Also, that sounds more like a comment than an answer.

Answer (score 7):

While posting exact duplicate answers is against the rules, there are two situations in which  there really isn't an obvious and decent alternative:

1. The exact same answer applies to two questions, yet they are not duplicates and should not be closed as such. For instance, given the questions

   > I have problem A; how can I solve it by doing X or Y?

   and

   > I have problem B; how can I solve it by doing Y or Z?

   and

   > I have problem C, how can I solve it by doing Z or X?

   we find ourselves in a pickle. These questions, despite suggesting a couple of solutions, may well each be well-specified enough that they deserve to continue to exist and not be closed as too broad. However, none of them is an exact duplicate of another, nor even contained fully within the scope of another, so we can't use dupe closure.

   I think I've seen a few of these scenarios, although I failed to track a single one down over 15 minutes of trying so take that claim with a pinch of salt. In particular, they often happen with array manipulation questions involving maps and filters, where some language has a standard way of performing a map or filter operation but also has a bunch of specialised map or filter functions for specific tasks such as plucking an object out of an array based upon the value of one of its properties, or uppercasing all strings in an array, or whatever. In such situations, lots of questions that amount to 'How can I perform this map or filter operation *on this specific data*' can be validly answered with a standard answer about how to use the language's map and filter functions, but may not be duplicates because there's a specialised function for the asker's particular case.

   In this situation, somebody who has an answer that's equally valid to two questions faces an awkward choice. They can either:

   - Post on only one question, leaving viewers of the other without the benefit of their wisdom, which sucks.
   - Post a full answer on one question and a comment linking to it on the other, which both reduces its visibility enormously if the comments thread is large and also stops the community from voting on it to let visitors see how folks feel it compares to the other answers on the question. This way sucks too.
   - Post a full answer on one question, and a link-only answer on the other, which falls foul of the 'no link-only answers' rule, which sucks.
   - Post an exact duplicate answer, which falls foul of the "don't post an exact duplicate answer" rule, which sucks.

   Faced with four choices which all suck, I don't think that somebody who chooses the last one in good faith deserves to be 'punished'. Indeed, in some circumstances I might well defend it as the best of those four choices, especially if the answer is very short (e.g. a one-liner).
2. The other situation in which cross-posting an answer may be the smallest of the evils available to you is this:

   - Somebody posts a question
   - You answer it very well
   - Your answer gets accepted
   - It gets correctly closed as a duplicate of some other, far more popular question that you never knew about when you answered
   - You look at the other question and see that your answer is better than all the answers there

   If your answer hadn't been accepted, you could just delete it and then post it on the more popular question instead. However, you now don't have that option. Probably what I'd do in these circumstances is cross-post and then flag the original asking a moderator to delete it, explaining the circumstances. But perhaps somebody doesn't realise that such a thing is possible, or doesn't think it's worth bothering the mods over. Once again, I don't think they should be punished for trying in good faith to find the best compromise in an awkward and irritating situation.

In addition to the above edge cases, one scenario that I suspect is common is that a new user doesn't know about duplicate close voting, doesn't have the rep for it, or doesn't feel comfortable using it. In such situations, punishment once again doesn't seem appropriate (at least on a first offence) for a user trying to do the best they can with the tools at their disposal.

Comment: You missed out another option: Post an answer on one question explaining how to do X and why it solves problem A. Post a different answer on the other question explaining how to do X and why it solves problem C. A large part of the answer text might be the same, but the part which intelligently and thoughtfully contextualizes the solution and discusses how the OP might proceed is not.

Comment: +1 This is my opinion. I even did this myself once: I answered [this question on Music.SE](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/13916/common-patterns-in-music/13917#13917), then copied part of my answer for [this related but non-duplicate question](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/17641/how-can-i-practice-harmony/17680#17680).