# How to make images stand out when posting images with whitespace?

Tags: discussion, markdown, images

Sometimes we have to post images with lots of whitespace, which really does not stand out in the white background of Stack Overflow:

[image]

This can be extremely [confusing when we post the images of the site itself](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/266465/1), for example in Meta.

Is there a simple way to make images with whitespace stand out against the white background of the site?

Comment: [I'd use `Paint` and the `Rectangle` tool with no fill ;)](http://oi62.tinypic.com/npoqcm.jpg)

Comment: @mehow: [Ain't nobody got time for that](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8cT_Ulmcrys)

Comment: hhah yeah I agree BUT I was just saying cause I actually put effort into asking and try to make sure my questions are spot on before I hit `POST YOUR QUESTION` ;) btw. ++ to your Q&A

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138594/do-images-need-a-border-around-them

Comment: You can use [freehand circles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775) :)

Comment: @mehow - GIMP with a Drop Shadow. Its takes three clicks: Filters -> Light and Shadow -> Drop Shadow... Four clicks if your count the right click for "Open with GIMP".

Comment: @jww: You will also need to scale the image or expand the canvas. Otherwise the drop shadow will be outside the drawing area/canvas.

Comment: @Krumia - GIMP does it automatically if you leave "Allow Resizing" checked. See [Drop Shadows](http://docs.gimp.org/en/script-fu-drop-shadow.html) in the GIMP docs.

Answer (score 44):

<sub>I was inspired to write this question because of a neat trick [gnat](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/839601/gnat) used on [one of my answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266465/1461424) to solve this problem.</sub>

You can just put the image inside a blockquote. This will add a nice shaded background to the image.

**Markup:**

```
> ![image description][1]

   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbEOF.png
```

**Result:**

> [image]

*Note:* The blockquote element in mobile site is handled in a different way. So you don't get the shaded background in the mobile site. So mobiles site shows pictures pretty much same with or without this trick. So you can use this trick to make your picture to stand out *at least* in non-mobile versions of the site.

Comment: Just a note: That doesn't really work on the mobile site.

Comment: @MikeM.: Then that should be reported as a bug, I think. (If not there's a design decision that blockquotes should only contain text).

Comment: It's not a bug. Block quotes are handled differently on the mobile site. Instead of the grey background, they have a blue vertical line on the left.

Comment: Well I have never used the mobile site. If that's so it definitely reduces the usability of this trick.

Comment: You can check it out. There's a "mobile" link in the page footer, near "contact us".

Comment: Yup, that is aweful. But it makes not much difference than the picture without the blockquote. So that's not a reason not to use the trick. But I will add this finding to the answer.

Comment: Yeah, like I said, it was just a note. Your answer does explain why I've seen people quoting images, however, so thanks for that.

Comment: Yeah, but it doesn't make me nervous :-(

Comment: I think this might be most semantically correct approach for screenshots.  After all, a screenshot is a way of "quoting" the screen.

Answer (score 38):

Here's a different way.  Works on mobile, too.

<kbd>[image: image description]</kbd>

`<kbd>![image description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbEOF.png)</kbd>`

Bonus:  you piss off the semantic web dweebs.  Oh, and OCPD folks once they realize that the margins aren't even.  Look at the margins.  Does it make you feel nervous?  Does it?

for the OCPD sensitive, you can use this helpfully provided update:

And like this to add a "padding-top":

<kbd>[image: image description]</kbd>

```
<kbd>  
![image description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbEOF.png)</kbd>
```

Comment: Best "misuse" of the `kbd` tag for ages :)

Comment: Makes me very nervous, and I'm not a semantic anything :)

Comment: I don't see that button on my keyboard. Where can I find it?

Comment: @Kev: _Only_ use of `kbd` tag for ages. I hear that there's a celebration at W3C.

Comment: I added a way to reduce the [nervousness](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/270195/1) of the margins. Hope you don't mind :) . . . PS: not really sure why the OCD observation was stripped out. Voting to reinstate.

Comment: Ahhh! The padded top! *I'm still nervous!!!* :(

Comment: FYI, if you try to use the `<kbd>` for this, be aware that it breaks the site on large images in certain web browsers, as mentioned here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/363914

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps a css `box-shadow` for post-text images?

```css
.post-text img { 
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,.75) 
}
```

```html
<div class="post-text">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbEOF.png">
</div>
```

Comment: Yay! Stack Snippets!

Comment: No way! This will kill pie charts and other non-rectangular data. Only acceptable as a comment triggered option `<!-- image: shadow -->` but in this case I would go with a simple 1px gray border. `<!-- image: border-->`

Answer (score 4):

Here's an easy way with GIMP. Open the image, then *Filters → Light and Shadow → Drop Shadow...*.

If you leave "Allow Resizing* checked, then GIMP will properly size the canvas for you based on the blur radius. See [Drop Shadows](http://docs.gimp.org/en/script-fu-drop-shadow.html) in the GIMP docs.

The image below took about 10 seconds to open, add the effect and save. I think it totaled about 5 mouse clicks. Most of the time was spent while GIMP was starting up.

[image]

Comment: yeah, but neither do I use Gimp not would I want to change the original Image; it is sometimes used to test things and a changed version just won't do!

Comment: That’s really outside of the scope of the question, which is about how to *post* images and make them standout on Stack Exchange, not how to *edit* images to make them stand out anywhere. If someone asks how to frame an oil painting, the answer is expected to involve building wooden or metal frames for the paintings, not how to paint black borders around the edge of the canvas with oil paints, which is impractical.

Comment: @Simon - the poster asked: *"Is there a simple way to make images with whitespace stand out against the white background of the site"*. This is a simple way. Not only is it simple, its attractive. I'm not sure where you are reading those additional requirements.

Comment: @TaW - Do whatever works for you. If you don't know how to use GIMP, then use something else. I haven't come across a case where a drop shadow broke a question, and I've performed it for a number of folks. See, for example, [How to make my drawing move inside HTML5 canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25420261/how-to-make-my-drawing-move-inside-html5-canvas).

Comment: Well, it needn't but it can. If an image is to be analyzed I'd rather not change it. And I love those <kdb> tags..

Comment: @TaW - sure, it can break a question. But I have not encountered such a question (yet). You're complaining about a problem that does not seem to exist. If you don't want to do it, then that's fine. Move on.

Comment: @jww does it work for `.gif` image?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not crazy about them in general, and I prefer the quoting approach mentioned in [another answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270148/1281433) for screenshots since a screenshot is a sort of quotation of the screen, but how about some horizontal rules?

```
----

![some black shapes on a white background][2]

----
```

produces

---

[image: some black shapes on a white background]

---