# Suggested edits queue: different number of buttons at different reviews

Tags: bug, review-queues, suggested-edits

Preface: This is no question about the disappearence of "too minor". I'm fully aware of that fact.

On some reviews I had this evening only the choice between

- Approve
- Reject
- Skip

Those were not only "tag edits". I'm very sure I encountered this behavior at edits of regular questions like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5758699), now deleted.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

I remember especially [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5758699), now deleted. I was about to improve it, but couldn't because I had only the choice between "Approve", "Reject" and "Skip" as said. It's a pity that I didn't thought about taking a screenshot of this question.

On other posts I've got all five like before

<kbd>[image: all five]</kbd>

Just now I've had this issue with a normal question. As I tried to check the question I saw that the question was deleted by the author.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Is this a bug or is there a cause for this?

I think there's a cause for this: Those three buttons will be shown if the question (or answer) with the suggested edit is already deleted.

Comment: Your first screenshot is a tag wiki, the second is a regular post.

Comment: I encountered the same by regular edits of questions and answers too.

Comment: @gnat That is a horrible abuse of the `<kbd>` tag. I like it!

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot [blame Will](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270195/839601) :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Tag wikis

A [similar question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/95520/234299) was asked on Meta SE. [Gilles's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/96233/234299):

> ...you can only `Improve` a post if you would have the right to edit it unsupervised. For questions and answers, the requirement is the same as approving edits: [2000 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit). For tag wikis, you can **approve at [5000](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits)** reputation, but you need **[20000](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/trusted-user) to make your own** unsupervised edit. So as long as you're in the 5k-20k range, you can approve or reject tag wiki suggeted [sic] edits but not `Improve` them.

### Deleted posts

Along the same lines, only 10k users can view other people's deleted posts. If you have [full editing privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) (2000 rep), you can [edit deleted posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/179769/234299). However, according to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/109645/234299)<sup>*</sup>, edits to deleted posts by users under 10k are put in the suggested edit queue instead of being applied directly. By extension, I'm guessing that users in the 2k-10k range can <kbd>Approve</kbd> and <kbd>Reject</kbd> suggested edits to deleted posts, but not <kbd>Improve</kbd> them.

---

* I was unable to find this substantiated in any other Meta posts. Anybody have a reliable source to back this up?

Comment: Tag wiki's not the only case. I encountered that at normal questions too. I couldn't improve [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5758699) so I choose "Reject".

Comment: Show a screenshot of a normal question or answer where you encountered this.

Comment: I've got to wait until tomorrow. I didn't thought to create screenshots right from the start and had only a few reviews left.

Comment: @VMai Were you able to reproduce your issue with a normal post?

Comment: I think my memory had played a trick on me. I couldn't reproduce this, so I think I was mistaken.

Comment: Today I met this issue. So it seems to happen in rare cases.

Comment: I tried to check the question and the question was already deleted. I think that's the cause for seeing only three buttons then.

Comment: That makes sense. You would need to have 10k to edit a deleted post (other than your own). You didn't take a screenshot this time, did you? It would be nice to have something verifiable to add to the answer.

Comment: I did, the third one, now nicely enclosed in <kbd> by gnat. "Can't convert string to date in android"

Comment: Ah, missed that, thanks. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I didn't knew that with 10k one could edit deleted posts of others. And yes, that makes perfect sense. I understand why it's difficult to reproduce it: you've got to have a deleted post with a edit pending in the suggested edits queue.

Comment: Well, only 10k users can *view* other people's deleted posts. I'm guessing by extension that only 10k users can improve suggested edits to deleted posts. See my latest edit.

Comment: It seems to be the #3 that [Shog mentions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99593/how-is-the-editing-of-deleted-posts-supposed-to-behave/179769#179769), because those were questions deleted by the author self (#2). That narrows the margin for an encounter even more, because I could have edit a question deleted by say a mod or > 10k users. I'm surprised I get at least two cases in less than two weeks.

Comment: I'm not too surprised. There is a massive flow of crap questions into the site. Some people try to clean them up by editing, and others by closing/deleting. Sometimes both will happen around the same time.

Comment: I read Shogs answer again because it's the newest one there. My conclusions are: a) It's got to be a self-deleted question, else I can edit the deleted post because editing and viewing privileges don't align. b) I wouldn't have edit buttons even with more than 10k reputation.