# Account for "&nbsp;" in empty body check

Tags: feature-request

I just saw someone answer a question, realise it was wrong and delete it. All fine, but they then edited the answer to simply be a sequence of `&nbsp;` hence making the answer empty and as it was within the 5 minute window there is no history. So like this:

```
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
```

I suppose it's not too bad for a deleted answer but I assume it can be abused to expand really short answers/questions.

So, can the check that warns that the body isn't 30 chars long check for this?

Comment: Why do you want to see an answer that the answerer clearly felt was wrong enough to be unsalvageable?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137006/dont-count-non-printing-characters-html-comments-or-other-content-not-displaye

Comment: @DavidThomas I didn't say I want to see those, I just don't want people to be able to 'game' the system to enter nonsense.

Comment: A post that was nonsensical, and/or gaming the system, will be down voted, flagged and deleted. Once that's done what purpose do you feel is met by preventing the obliteration of their content?

Comment: @DavidG the only filter you could implement where people will be unable to "game the system to enter nonsense" would be one where _all_ posts are rejected regardless of content.

Comment: @DavidThomas So why have the 30 character limit then?

Comment: @DavidG It makes people think about whether they should expand their answer. People will always find ways round this. But the current system ensures it is a conscious decision. If they think about it and decide to bypass the restriction and the resulting answer is crap the system will take care of it with downvotes and delete votes.

Answer (score 3):

This check would have to account for other similar not-so-visible HTML entities as well as HTML comments. I just posted an answer containing nothing but a HTML comment, and that also *bypassed* the character check.

```
<!-- A long enough HTML comment... -->
```

[image: Example]

Comment: wrap it one more time. or more than one more time :D

Comment: @gunr2171 please don't use `<kbd>` tags for decoration.

Comment: I thought that's what was needed. If I remember correctly, [blockquoted images don't look correct on mobile](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270195/1043380), but `kbd` do. I'll refrain in the future.

Comment: @gunr2171 Interesting. Sounds like a problem which the StackExchange developers need to address though, rather than users getting around it with invalid syntax.

Answer (score 2):

There is also this [famous answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/41991/231078) from a joke question on meta.stackexchange.com which [consists of](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/029f1ee7-ef61-4d2a-b695-bd36724a0b03/view-source):

```
Yes.<blah><blah><blah>
```

Of course, when a user encloses something in angle brackets and it doesn't render it's usually an accident. How would the check account for accidents?

Comment: By blocking submission and highlighting what didn't render, so the user can fix it.  We want to prevent accidents, too.

Comment: A more famous example http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116918