# Highlighting border for images

Tags: feature-request, markdown, images

I regularly find questions on SO with bright images inlined which appear as if they are part of the layout. Actually I just came accross [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18635132/json-object-with-or-without-quotes). It bugs me a little and I think a highlighting border would be an improvement because it clearly distinguishes the layout.

Answer (score 3):

Either put the image in a blockquote, or use the `<kbd>` tag to produce a border:

### Blockquote

> [image: cute Ninja]

Markdown source:

```
> ![cute Ninja][1]
```

### Keyboard tag

<kbd>[image: cute Ninja]</kbd>

Markdown source:

```
<kbd>![cute Ninja][1]</kbd>
```

The latter works better for the mobile view than the former.

Comment: Use a blockquote. Don't abuse the `<kbd>` element for this.

Comment: @animuson: abuse shmabuse.

Comment: I was looking for a more definite solution, not everyone uses that.

Comment: @toplel32: not everyone uses code blocks or emphasis either. This works and *a lot* of people do use it.

Comment: @animuson as opposed to quotes, [kbd is known to work on mobile](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270195/839601)

Comment: @gnat That's not a good reason to use it for an inappropriate purpose.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - Atleast users are expected to use code blocks, else an edit will follow, that doesn't seem the case here.