# Why is a post with six recommended deletion votes still not deleted?

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts, deletion

I see that [this post review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/8793400) has six recommend deletion votes. I thought it would be deleted by now. Is there a reason it is not deleted?

The review screen shot in case the post gets deleted:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Comment: Hm, weird, the review shows as "completed", yet the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8100770/auto-scaling-inputtype-text-to-width-of-value/8100825#8100825) remains.

Comment: Two instances of that answerer's nickname have upvoted the answer. Maybe that was preventing outright deletion. It's back in the negatives now (and will soon be deleted).

Comment: Curiosity: is this question designed to trigger the meta effect? ;)

Comment: @Gimby, when review queues don't work... you know who to call.

Comment: @Gimby I doubt it, it's obviously a weird outcome of a review, hence a good question, in my opinion. This is one of the rare posts that actually needs a link trail to the post in question.

Comment: @PeterMortensen kbd for images has been [explained in details here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270195/839601). If you're interested,  comparison against more traditional blockquote is [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/277568/839601)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Due to positive score at the moment of review completion, post is not eligible for immediate deletion.

Six votes for deletion in this case only raise a system flag for moderator attention ("DisputedLowQuality"). This is explained in details in [this post at MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/226092/165773), condition "post scores > 0":

> Task accumulates 6 RecommendDelete + Delete reviews.
>   **Outcome:** mark flags "helpful". If the post scores > 0 then raise DisputedLowQuality mod flag, else just delete post...

---

More generally, unattended deletion happens *only* when there is sort of a solid consensus of "all parties involved". When there is such a consensus, it's really easy to see it, built on an unambiguous agreement of reviewers and voters that answer isn't worth keeping, followed by total negligence of the answerer.

Anything that distorts above consensus - positive score, accept mark, [author disagreement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184568/165773) - anything like that gets escalated to mod attention and deletion is postponed until moderator decides on it. That's sort of protection against possible review mistakes.

Comment: Now due to the meta effect it has got a negative score. So will the Recommended Deletion votes be still valid? The answer got deleted is it due to Recommended Deletion or delete votes by 10k+ users?

Comment: Hate to have to point this out, but... Recommending deletion is just that: a *recommendation*. Either the system, 10k users, or a moderator will consider this recommendation and delete or not. @Ram I went ahead and deleted this particular answer.

Comment: @Ram in this particular case, main reason for deletion is ["meta effect"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269349/839601), it doesn't matter much whether it was done by moderator or "trusted" (20K) users. Without meta exposure, system flag would get to moderator, and they would likely delete it (answer does look really poor and score is not high)

Comment: "At first glance, it seems that just six-seven 2K users can in theory create a death ring and remove 20 _any_ answers a day... But system is indeed designed to prevent anything like this from happening..." ([Mob rules, balanced](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/2584/168))