# 1509 upvotes, but in Review Low Quality Posts queue!

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/8829207), which I thought was a test review, turned out to be genuine. Whilst I suppose the humour in the first line might grate against some people, the answer is perfectly correct and perhaps only suffers from a lack of links to the standard.

I'm not really sure if I have a real question, it just seemed odd for this answer to end up in the review queue. I suppose I could ask **"Is sarcastic humour allowed in valid answers to genuine questions?"**, or even **"How should I deal with po-faced moderation flags?"**.

Comment: It was posted 5 years ago when the rules were more lax, and it seems that it was picked up by the heuristics. Probably triggered by the recent edit. No matter, it is a low quality answer and should either be edited or deleted. Looking at the other answers to the same question, I would err on the side of deletion. Although, it looks like the robo-reviewers are getting to it, so it may stick around.

Comment: To be honest: I had to *really* search for this specific answer in the  question page among the many answers available. The majority of those answers basically say exactly the same, just without the joke.

Comment: @TinyGiant, in light of http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-it-is-not-an-answer, why should that answer be deleted? It seems to me that even if you think it's bad, it's an honest (and successful) attempt to answer the question.

Comment: @Kenster That link is about NaA, this discussion is about VLQ.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The answer to your second question is the same as the answer to your first question, which is *use your best judgement*.

I tend to appreciate witticisms and creative humor provided that they don't obfuscate or upstage the actual information being provided. Write for the person that frowns on funny business and make them happy with great detail; don't use a crap answer to cash in on the opportunity to make a joke - and it's generally tolerated. Pulling this off in the framework of high signal Q&A is something of an accomplishment.

The one you linked has a bit of a sordid past. It was once deleted, the community brought it back, and it tends to attract flags each time something bumps that question.

It does answer the question, it does make some people chuckle, I see no reason for it not to exist. If you feel differently, that's completely up to you, and you should use the tools you have available to express that.

Put more simply, there's really no blanket *rule* where individual discretion is prescribed.

Comment: Interestingly, 2 of 5 reviewers recommended deletion.  Would be unfortunate to delete something with 1500+ upvotes if a few more people whose individual judgement swayed the other way happened to be assigned that answer.  Those few voices would outweigh the 1500+ that found it useful.

Comment: @EricJ. Answers with a positive score are never deleted directly from review. If the reviewers recommended deletion, the recommendation would go up for moderator review. Tangentially: an upvote can mean "this is useful" or "LOL, funny".

Comment: I didn't know that there was an additional moderator review step.  Good to know.  An upvote can also mean "this guy helped me on a different problem and I like him", "I'm in a good mood today", or "I clicked on the wrong arrow."  Statistically I would assume that most upvotes actually mean the question/answer is useful.

Comment: @EricJ. see [Why is a post with six recommended deletion votes still not deleted?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/299376/839601) "At first glance, it seems that just six-seven 2K users can in theory create a death ring and remove 20 _any_ answers a day... But system is indeed designed to prevent anything like this from happening..." As for statistics, it rather tends to split most-upvotes between genuinely useful and plainly-fun stuff, see [The Trouble With Popularity](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2012/01/the-trouble-with-popularity/): "it's too addictive and too easy"

Answer (score 8):

A canonical reference would be [Jeff Atwood's post on humor](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2010/01/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/). Concerning questions, where SO is way more strict than answers, he gives three criteria:

> 1. Does this question match the criteria provided in the Stack Overflow
>      FAQ?
> 2. Is this question accepted by the community, as reflected in upvotes, favorites, views, and answers?
> 3. Does this question teach me anything that could make me better at my job? Can I learn something from it?

And then concludes

> As Meat Loaf once said, **two out of three ain't bad**. It's guideline #3
>   that ends up being the pivotal decision in most borderline cases.

Applying above to this answer: it *is* accepted by the community (1520 upvotes) **and** it teaches something ....

Seems like a clear accept.