# Why can I undelete a moderator-deleted post?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, moderation

Previously, I was below 50 reputation. Some of my 'answers' looked more like comments than answers, and one particular commanswer was flagged and deleted.

However, due to an upvote on said commanswer, I was put above 50 reputation and able to make real comments. Why was I able to restore my answer, and retain the reputation, despite the post that gave me the reputation having been deleted?

**EDIT** Link: [Three.js - Rotate object along (0,0,0) on mouse move](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34340977/three-js-rotate-object-along-0-0-0-on-mouse-move/34341417#34341417)

Comment: Perhaps link to the post? It might be easier to see what's going on if we can see the post. Though I have a feeling is "A moderator didn't do it, three high-rep users did." But it's hard to confirm that without knowing what post to look at.

Comment: More information is always good, however I don't think that would be pertinent to my question; 'why can I undelete a moderator-deleted post?' (I.E. my own post)

Comment: That's what I'm saying though- If you undeleted a moderator-deleted (as in, a diamond moderator) post, that shouldn't happen. But if you undeleted a post that was deleted by three high-rep users, that has a different response.

Comment: I guess if there are other public users of this service that have a power over the rest of us, my question may be flawed in itself

Comment: I know what happened now- Give me just a moment and I'll type up an answer for you. :)

Comment: ["...author disagreement... gets escalated to mod attention and deletion is postponed until moderator decides on it. That's sort of protection against possible review mistakes."](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/299376/839601)

Answer (score 4):

So here's the timeline of what happened:

1. Something, most likely a flag, sent your answer to the Low Quality Review Queue.
2. In the queue, your post was [voted as "Recommend Deletion"](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/10602994) which deleted the post.
3. Since your post was not deleted by a diamond moderator (users with a ♦ next to their user name), it was able to be undeleted. Since your post was not deleted by three users with 20k+ reputation but instead by lower reputation users simply *recommending* deletion, you were able to self-undelete.

From the [Deletion FAQ on Meta Stack Exchange:](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that)

> Normally, if your deleted post is not self-deleted, you can't undelete it yourself (though you may be able to vote to undelete). An exception: if an answer is deleted from Low Quality review queue by "Recommend Deletion" votes, without three trusted users voting to delete, then [it can be undeleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228479/259867) by the author.

So, normally, you would not have been able to undelete this post. However, since the review queue deleted it via a "Recommend Deletion" vote rather than a "Delete" vote, you were still able to undelete your post. Had one more 20k+ user given a "Delete" vote on that review, you would not have been able to undelete this answer and it would instead require three undelete votes.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks. I assume the Low Quality review queue is only accessible by users with a minimum reputation?

Comment: @AndrueAnderson Yes. You need at least 2k reputation to review in that queue, and until you hit 20k rep, you can only recommend deletion of a post. I will add that since your answer is _not an answer_ (That's one of the flag types if you hadn't ever looked at them) do expect it to be deleted again, if you don't re-delete it yourself. The answer section is not for comments or requests for clarification, regardless of whether you have enough reputation to comment. Lack of ability to do something is not a good reason to break the rules.

Comment: Personally, I disagree with your implication that the act was primarily a transgression of the rules as opposed to an attempt to work with a broken system. In that situation, out of curiosity, what would have been the correct way to comment given no comment ability?

Comment: You can always comment on your own posts @Andrue, there's no reputation restriction on that.

Comment: @Ben it was not my own post

Comment: @AndrueAnderson The correct way would have been to move on. The system is not broken- It is as it is for a reason. Comments are not as easily monitored as questions and answers, and therefore are more vulnerable to spam. To prevent this, there is the minimum reputation requirement. As it is, the rule is not to use the answer section for posting anything but answers. That you cannot yet comment otherwise is still no reason to break said rule.

Comment: @AndrueAnderson As it is, you're actually very close to 50 rep right now anyway. You get 2 rep for each suggested edit you make that gets accepted, did you know that? That is, up to 1000 rep gained that way. Perhaps you can find a couple posts to edit to get you over the edge. Please be sure that you edit everything you can in the post, and if the question isn't likely to stay open... I wouldn't waste your time.

Comment: Oh I didn't actually mean to benefit personally from this post, I thought that would be pretty clear given that I'm intentionally pointing out a 'rule breaking' on my part. In response to your previous comment, you seemed to imply that you'd answered my question by telling me 'there is no answer to that question, you have to move on instead' and then continued on with the rest of your comment based on what I saw as an assumption that you *had* answered my question, and that what you had said was relevant to the implication that you were correct in saying the system is not broken. False, btw.

Comment: @AndrueAnderson No, actually, the answer to your question wasn't "There is no answer." It was, indeed, "You move on." That _is_ the answer, and the guidance, on how to handle not having enough rep to comment. As I said, the system is not broken. It is not how you want it to be, but that does not make it broken. If I want to buy beer but I'm under 21, the system is not broken- I may not like it, but it's not broken. The only difference here is that the only "workaround" is not really that- You will get caught and your answers deleted. [This has been discussed before.](/q/250977/)

Comment: Perhaps you didn't understand the question, I said "What would have been the correct way to comment...?" Which means, if no comment is made, then your response is *not* an answer to the question of how to comment. In the example you provided, while it is applicable to real life, does not contain any *actual* information about the system described, only information about the state of your 'liking' which doesn't actually prove anything or carry over to this situation where the system doesn't allow comments, but enforces a negative feedback loop. Why are you so adamant that someone caught me?

Comment: I made the post myself, if anything I turned myself in...of course that's to imply I did something wrong. And while your answer may be the *accepted* answer to the question *I'm asking in this situation* that doesn't make it the *correct* answer to *the question in general*

Comment: Last I'm going to bother to try to explain this- If this does not clarify _my_ meaning to you, then it might just be best you search meta/ask a new question (since this is really not the point of your original meta question.) If you ask "How can I do x?" and you can't, then a correct answer is, "You can't. Move on." It is an appropriate answer, _especially_ if there is not a real work around. Just because you don't like the answer does not mean it is not an answer. If you _disagree_ with the policy of 50 rep to comment, I suggest you search previous topics and try to raise a feature request.

Comment: _"And while your answer may be the accepted answer to the question"_ I lied, you raised one more point worth addressing. The rules here are, mostly, made by the community. If the community agrees an answer is _the_ accepted answer, then that is the _correct_ answer until such time as the discussion is revisited and the consensus changes. (It can/has happened.) If you _disagree_ with the community's rules... You're part of the community. Make a constructive post and try to have a discussion to change it. If you don't succeed, you may learn something you didn't realize. @AndrueAnderson

Comment: I can see that the issue is the disparity between an *answer* to a question and a *solution* to a problem. You're providing me a solution, I asked for an answer. Thank you. Your time spent plowing through the rules has been validated. Carry on. "If the community agrees an answer is the accepted answer, then that is the correct answer" - what happens when the community decides 2+2=5? Is that still the correct answer? Can you see the difference yet?

Comment: _"what happens when the community decides 2+2=5? Is that still the correct answer? Can you see the difference yet?"_ You're arguing completely different ideas here, my friend. We're talking about changing rules of the site. _You_ are talking about a mathmatical equation that does not change the same way. Apples and oranges. As I said, the community makes the rules for the community. The community does not make the rules for other things. If you disagree with the rules of the community, you are allowed to try to change it. But debating here with me isn't going to do that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98363/discussion-between-andrue-anderson-and-kendra).