# How does the LQPRQ work?

Tags: support, review-queues, low-quality-posts

My question came up, when I noticed that a *NAA* flag of mine got disputed. I had a look at the [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/11487905) and read that the review completed with 3 votes for and 3 against deletion. I wondered how this decides the review.
I would have imagined it to require a 3 vote lead for any option, just like in Triage - but that should have gotten the post deleted, now we have a 3/3.

I had a look on meta, but did not find an answer, and both the [review](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues) and [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) privilege sites in the help center did not include this information, as well as [this post on meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161390/what-are-the-review-queues-and-how-do-they-work).

My question is:
**How does the low quality posts review queue work, and based on how many votes is a decision formed?**

<s>(What also bugs me a little is, that the answer in question should IMHO definitely be deleted, as it is a new question, am I wrong here?)</s>
*I want to know about the voting process within the LQPRQ. The answer itself is **not** the point of my question so this question is absolutely different to the posted "duplicate".*

Comment: Its been deleted now.

Comment: details of review in LQ queue are explained in [this MSE post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/226092/165773). See also: [Why is a post with six recommended deletion votes still not deleted?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/299376/839601)

Comment: I [reposted compilation of MSE stuff into answer here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/318754/839601) (made it CW bacause it's mostly not mine and to make it easier for others to update, as it appears to be regularly changing)

Comment: you are wasting your time with the NAA flag, just stay away from it unless the body of the text is just gibberish, anything that is readable is going to get declined, **attempt to answer** has an extremely liberal definition now. *Have you tried X?* is generally declined as it is considered an attempt to answer if reworded to *You should try X!*.

Comment: This is surely not a duplicate of this question.  My question is not about the answer but how the voting in the LQRQ works.  Also, as you have >10k, please have a read of the deleted answer. It did not try to answer the question but was a "I have the same problem,  what is the solution?"  answer,  which is NAA

Answer (score 19, accepted):

<sup>Repost from respective MSE discussions on implementation details.</sup>

[Details of LQRQ are explained here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/226092/165773)...

> Not an Answer flags go into /review/low-quality, [just like Very Low Quality flags already do](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181165/can-flags-send-a-post-into-the-low-quality-posts-review-queue/190639#190639).
>
> Then we beef up the Low Quality review process to make better use of more experienced reviewers and solve this whole "declined / helpful / disputed" flag debate once and for all:
>
> - Effective # of reviews required == ReviewsRequired + # of applicable flags (where ReviewsRequired is 2 on Stack Overflow, 1 everywhere else). So 1 VLQ or NAA flag means `EffectiveReviewsRequired`=3.
> - LQ tasks are not dequeued until one of the following conditions is met:
>
>   1. Post is edited from within review.
>        **Outcome:** flags are marked "helpful" (current behavior).
>   2. Post accumulates 3 Delete votes (can only happen when post scores <= 0 and reviewers have >= 20K rep).
>        **Outcome:** post is deleted, flags are marked "helpful".
>   3. Task accumulates `EffectiveReviewsRequired` "Looks Good" reviews.
>        **Outcome:** if the number of (Recommend)Delete reviews is >= the number of Looks Good reviews, mark flags "disputed" and raise DisputedLowQuality mod flag. Otherwise, mark flags "declined".
>   4. Task accumulates 4 RecommendDelete or Delete reviews.
>        **Outcome:** mark flags "helpful". If the post scores > 0 or is accepted then raise DisputedLowQuality mod flag, else just delete post (current behavior).
> - As under the current system, flags on posts that've already completed one full review cycle without being deleted should skip /review and go directly into the mod queue.

...and [further clarified here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228861/165773):

> here's a somewhat more readable summary of the rules:
>
> 1. VLQ and NAA flags immediately <sup>(obsolete - see below)</sup> enter the mod flag queue in all cases
> 2. VLQ and NAA flags *on posts that have not been previously reviewed* and are not closed, deleted, locked or accepted will enter /review/low-quality-posts.
> 3. If review completes successfully, the flag is marked handled and removed from the mod flag queue
> 4. If all mod-flags on a post are dismissed from the moderator flag queue, the review task is invalidated
> 5. If the outcome of review is deletion, and a post's score prevents it from being deleted, the original flags will be marked "helpful". In these cases, and in cases where the flags are disputed, a new, moderator-only flag will be raised on the post.

One later correction to above process is that [flags do not always enter mod flag queue *immediately*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/247658/165773). Delays are dependent on the site and may change and initially were configured as follows:

> Very Low Quality and Not An Answer flags do not enter the moderator queue for 15 minutes after they're raised. This applies network-wide, except on Stack Overflow, Mathematics, TeX, Salesforce and Stack Overflow em Português (where the delay is a full hour) and meta sites (where they enter the queue immediately).