# How is "I think [technology] is smarter than you" an answer?

Tags: discussion, not-an-answer

Some time ago I flagged an answer as not an answer which simply states the following:

> i think gcc is smarter than you in this case

Now, this is definitely not an answer. The question is clearly phrased, maybe not the cleverest one, but it is still a valid question.

Even if this had been posted as a comment I wouldn’t be surprised to see it being removed (especially with regard to the recent efforts to be more welcoming.)

My flag was deemed helpful but the answer is still there. Why? Was this just plain oversight?

Comment: Moderators don't enjoy having to destroy posts with that many votes.  We can make their job a little easier, done.

Comment: @HansPassant While the effort is a great thing... I feel like your edit put words in the answerers mouth. That might not be what they were referring to.

Comment: Come on dude, everybody knows who put that cast in the code. Reserve the tar and feathers for another day.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the LQRQ work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318744/how-does-the-lqrq-work)

Comment: @Hack-R: It seems to be https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362420/how-to-type-cast-a-literal-in-c

Comment: It's an interesting complication that it's a good answer after the edit. That should be discussed here too. On the one hand, from the perspective of building a good DB of Q&A we should let it stand. But OTOH rep ethically should go to @HansPassant instead of its OP, however by the rules vice versa.

Comment: Its fine, I would have posted the same answer if I dared.  I used to dare, not anymore.  Big bummer btw.

Comment: What is the context of this?  Without knowing the context, it is difficult to determine if "I think gcc is smarter than you in this case" perhaps meant something like "the gcc compiler may be transforming the code in [A] and [B] into the same assembly."

Answer (score 121):

All, answer author here.

Not very on point (regarding the flag and oversight), but I believe I should chime in on the answer itself.

Retrospectively looking - this is probably my worst answer of all on SO through out all the years I'm in the community. I will delete it. The answer was written "in the moment" with more emotions placed in it than thought, empathy and knowledge.

What's worse - I didn't know (and still don't) much if anything about casting literals in C (let alone casting literals in C on all GCC versions >= 4.0)

I wanted to look funny, but I understand that it made me look smug if not arrogant.

It doesn't help community's image either in that it shows a top 1% user not welcoming to newbies. Having reputation score that I do, I should lead with example. And this answer is not the one that is due.

Comment: That act deserves a lot of respect. Thank you.

Comment: Agreed with @BhargavRao, and given the answer is 9 (!!!!) years old and SO was a vastly different place than it is now, I think you're forgiven!

Comment: This is a seriously classy post. Total ownership of a something done nearly nine years ago, when (as DavidG points out) SO was a different place, without a hint of self-justification. Just pure class.

Comment: I agree with your analysis of your own answer - it comes across as a glib dismissal of the asker's question while not at all helping to answer it. I wouldn't self-flagellate too much over it, though. We've all written things that embarrass us in hindsight, and if this is your greatest sin to date then I don't think you've got much reason to feel guilty.

Comment: 9 years ago, did SO even have comments?

Comment: @Bergi: Yes, SO had comments when the answer was written.  They were there from very early on, if not from the very start.

Answer (score 22):

I handled the automatic flag raised on that post, and in hindsight, I probably should have deleted it at that time.

The post was flagged on the 11th, and the review concluded by the end of the next day and decided that the post should be deleted. As it was highly upvoted, it fell into the moderator queue. The disputed LQPQ mod queue at that time was over 150 flags (I remember this because my quarter end exams had concluded on June 15th evening, and what better way to enjoy some time off, other than blasting through the queue).

I saw this post in the mod queue on the June 16th, and the first thing I realized was that the queue had voted to delete it. Now, the standard way to handle a disputed LQPQ review is to check the answer, read the question, re-read the answer, then take action. My initial thought when I read the answer was similar to yours (that it's a non-answer and a slightly obtuse comment), however, my perspective changed when I read the question. The question was clear, the OP did try to "fool" the compiler by adding a simple cast which failed, and asked the reason for its failure. When I re-read the answer, the answer made complete sense, the compiler won't be fooled and thus the cast didn't work. Therefore I just cleared the flag and moved along.

I probably would have deleted the post, or atleast converted it to a comment if I had seen the entire question and the other answer, which would have given a clear signal to delete the post. I just saw the question and the answer from the queue and followed on with the normal technique. I am now still unsure whether to continue the current technique (which takes approximately 25~35 seconds) or to read the entire post for every flag (which takes more than 90~120 seconds). Thank you for helping me refine my technique, and sorry for the inconvenience caused.

Given that Hans has updated the answer, to make it more valid and answer-like, I think that it would be better to leave it as such. However, if you all (the community) decide that the answer needs to be deleted, feel free to poke me and I'll delete it.

Comment: As I said on a deleted comment, I personally think it's still no better than a comment. The question is "I did this, then I tried this work around, and it didn't work. Why didn't it work?" The answer, with the edit, is now basically "Well, it won't work." It doesn't explain anything, it just reiterates that the compiler does not see the cast as preventing the warning. =/ Granted, not my tech, that's just my outsider's reading of it.

Comment: I don't disagree with your argument @Kendra, but if a top user in that tag/technology has made changes to the post in order to save it from deletion, I would certainly give a bit of additional consideration to their act. I will wait for a couple of days, and if more people feel that it needs to be deleted, then I'll do it.

Comment: It is still not an answer.  I was still completely clueless as to the reasons why it didn't work after reading the one sentence.  However, the answer (currently) right below it explained it perfectly.