# LQR completed with 4 delete recommendations, 1 ok; the post remains - why?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, not-an-answer, link-only-answers

There is a [link-only answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15713303/2947502). Recently it went through a [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/18658103).

It ended with four delete-recommendations, one "ok".

[image]

The answer remains.

Shouldn't it actually get deleted? What rule keeps this answer posted?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228861/320339, it's probably waiting for mod (since old and upvoted).

Comment: A bit sad that no one saw fit to downvote that post. If anyone would have done that, it would have been deleted already.

Comment: The answer is in "If the outcome of review is deletion, and a post's score prevents it from being deleted, the original flags will be marked "helpful". In these cases, and in cases where the flags are disputed, a new, moderator-only flag will be raised on the post."

Comment: [Why is a post with six recommended deletion votes still not deleted?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/299373/839601)