# Declined flag - Is this answer "not an answer"?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, not-an-answer

The answer in question:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/57794403/4657412

I flagged this today as "not an answer" and it was declined (some of the other answers on the question were accepted as NAA, and deleted). It was reviewed as low quality in October 19 with 4 people recommending deletion, but that didn't cause it to get deleted.

It mainly appears to me to be a rant about the design of the specific webpage. The only sentence I think that could be an answer is

> Instead I had to discover a tiny soft grey button off to the upper right of my large display...

However, I don't think this actually relates to the original question asked. I believe instead this relates to

> Also why is the Manage Testers section of the screen default to closed.

which is an barely-related complaint also decided to make during their general venting about the webpage.

---

Ideally I'd like this to either be looked at again, or I guess for clarification that this is close enough to answering something that it should stay (and then I'll know not to flag this stuff in future).

Comment: It looks to be an answer of sorts, but a low-quality one

Comment: TBH, I'm not 100% sure that the original question that the "answer" tries to answer is a good fit for this site, and this will have bearing on the quality and appropriateness of the answers.

Comment: Why did that answer get a [unanimous 4 "Recommend Deletion"](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/24210036) from review, completing the review task, but did not get deleted as a result?

Comment: @CertainPerformance [Because the question has a positive score](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299373/why-is-a-post-with-six-recommended-deletion-votes-still-not-deleted).

Comment: @Ivar presumably it's because the _answer_ has a positive score?

Comment: @DavidW Ah yes, my bad. I meant the _post_ having a positive score.

Comment: So you didn't find that little gray button that the answer documents?  Well, some do and some don't, it is little and gray.  Are you ticked off because you didn't find it or because the answer reminded you that you should be able to find it?  Or you didn't need to find it and you're just ticked-off at the tone?  Hard to blame the tone.

Comment: Yes, the post annoyingly appears to answer the question stated. It’s a pretty bad answer of course, but there you have it.

Comment: In re-reading and cleaning up comments I can see that it is indeed just a rant and it’s been deleted. For edge-cases like these a custom moderator attention flag explaining the context is always appreciated.