# Can we have a button?

Tags: feature-request, markdown

People really really really like abusing the `<kbd>` html element for quasi-buttons. The `<kbd>` element is supposed to be used in situations where we want to signify a keyboard key (e.g. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to copy something).

Can we have special markup to create a button, or a button-like element? Just so people stop abusing another element for it?

Comment: Can you describe the kind of situation, or link to a post, where a button element would be useful?

Comment: muh semantic web!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/64440 http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/99/arrays#t=20160728074924197 I don't say they would be useful there. But people *really* want to abuse kbd there to create some kind of quasi snippet like thing.

Comment: Oh, is this a big thing on that there *Documentation* doohickey I keep hearing about?

Comment: People do it on SO too. I just don't see nearly as much answers on SO as I see edit suggestions on Docs right now.

Comment: I don't think that I've ever seen it. Anyway, I downvoted *both* posts for not bothering to explain the issue.

Comment: I guess [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270195/576767) would make you nervous :p

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier Yes, that makes me feel like burning someone with fire.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having a replacement will not stop people who want to abuse it, and regular hyperlinks work just fine. If you see someone abusing it, change it to a regular link via editing.

Comment: Why would a hyperlink be a meaningful replacement for a button?

Comment: *They're still hyperlinks*. No one actually wants buttons (that is, the behavior associated with buttons) to be used in these situations; button behavior is a subset of hyperlink behavior, you only lose functionality. The markup *looks like* a button, but still works like (and is...) a hyperlink. @Nisse. So what you get is a misleading appearance, and... Nothing else.

Comment: A misleading appearance is how I got my job and friends. Don't dismiss it too quickly.

Comment: Nobody expects `<kbd>` elements to behave like actual keypresses. Similarly, I would assume that a `<button>` element is meant to _appear_ like a button, not actually behave like one. Both posts are still missing some basic explanation.

Comment: @NisseEngström No, no-one would expect those elements to press actual keys on their keyboard. The correct usage however is to mark them like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/2288/console#t=201607281859136266859&a=remarks-opening-the-console-0) or like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/84/compile-and-run-your-first-java-program/4421/installing-java-development-kit#t=201607281900362306379).

Comment: @Sumurai8 both links are dead