# Making images stand out more

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

When an image is posted, I want it to stand out. Some solutions would be [to add a shadow to the image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270147/how-to-make-images-stand-out-when-posting-images-with-whitespace), but this is taking a too long time or does not produce the right effect.

As an example, if my uploaded image has no shadow and I give the label (such as `<kbd>` label), it will have shadow, to let the image stand out, add label is a easy way and can save many time.

[image]

Comment: You can post the suggestion right here on Meta. Don't hold your breath, though - the vast majority of suggestions will not be implemented.

Comment: @Pekka웃, do you mean the developers and owner of stackoverflow can see the suggestion on Meta?

Comment: Yes. ----------

Comment: I see it coming: A user posts code that fails to add a shadow to an image and posts the image as proof - and nobody can see the problem :p

Comment: Why does the image need to stand out? And if it really does, why can't you use an image editing program to add the shadow yourself?

Comment: @Copy Gray, First, form the link I post, so many up votes shows it is necessary, at least make the question more clear , but if use photoshop or other soft to edit, I think it will take time, and if there is a label(like `<kbd>`), to make shadow I think it is a convenient achievement.

Comment: I upvoted that question. I don't think it's necessary. So your claim is false.

Comment: @jakekimds, no, bro. my requirement is give a tag to let the image have shadow easy. that is my feature requirement. and your question is also contented in the link I give in my post.

Comment: @aircraft sorry. But still works for making the pictures stand out.

Answer (score 5):

This isn't something that we could easily do. While we do control the style where images are presented, we don't really have any idea (programmatically) what the image contains, and if any additional shadow or border would make it look worse. What if the image already contained a drop shadow, or what if someone wanted a series of small diagrams to join tightly with the text around them?

That's why we leave it up to folks to add any additional effects they think are needed prior to uploading. A tiny bit less convenient if you like having your images raise off the page a bit more, but leaving it up to the user seems like the best way to go. And, you can use the `<kbd>` or blockquote tricks if you don't feel like firing up an image editor.

There was a time where folks really wanted to be able to easily identify an image on mouseover, because people were taking a screenshot of their IDE in lieu of posting code (mainly to avoid detection by professors or managers). When we simply said "no, don't do that, we'll just remove it if you do" that problem largely went away.

Comment: There's still situations where an image without a border is hard to recognize, though. An optional Markdown tweak that would add a CSS shadow when needed *would* be cool.

Comment: Put a checkbox on the upload dialog for adding a dropshadow.  Tada! *glosses over implementation details that would probably prevent this from actually being something easy to accomplish*

Comment: @Pekka웃 That's easy to fix. Just quote the image using `>`