# Changes to discourage plagiarism

Tags: discussion, feature-request, etiquette, plagiarism

A large number of contributors have contributed high quality posts over the years on Stack Overflow, and the community collectively moderates to keep the standards of the site high. However, some users end up using other people's contributions and posts without attribution, which results in plagiarism.

At present, users can flag any such post for moderators' attention, and if sufficient evidence is found, then these posts are deleted by the moderators immediately.

However, in this process, the users don't get any immediate feedback, and may tend to continue borrowing other people's content without being aware that it is an incorrect practice, or consciously indulge in plagiarism in an attempt to gain reputation by copying highly-upvoted posts.

To encourage positive behavior and provide immediate feedback to a user, the following changes should be introduced:

- **User loses [X<sup>*</sup> reputation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269315/changes-to-discourage-plagiarism#comment82254_269315) every time one of their posts get deleted by a moderator as a result of a plagiarism flag.**

  This reputation loss will be visible to them as

  > -X<sup>*</sup>: [Plagiarized content deleted.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269315/changes-to-discourage-plagiarism#comment82239_269315ttp://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269315/changes-to-discourage-plagiarism#comment82239_269315) Please visit help center for more details.

  They should be able to see the link of the post which was deleted, similar to the linked posts we see for every upvote and downvote, and the help center link should lead them to information about plagiarism and guidelines for proper attribution.

  Reputation is a representation of trust, this deduction of reputation will indicate that trust is lost if one indulges in plagiarism.
- **Every post deleted due to plagiarism should count towards post ban.**

  The current post ban formula should take the flagged and deleted plagiarized posts of a user into consideration as a parameter, while computing post bans. These deleted plagiarised posts should weigh in even if they have zero or positive score.

  Users who have a high number of plagiarized posts will eventually hit the ban, and work on improving their content.
- [**Make posts removed for plagiarism exempt from the >60 day >3 score rule for keeping reputation.**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269315/changes-to-discourage-plagiarism#comment82245_269315)

  Users should not retain reputation gained by unfair means. It was never theirs to keep.

These measures will provide immediate feedback for innocent users and restrict those who may, at present, be willing to engage in plagiarism, and will encourage original content.

Thoughts?

---

<sup>*</sup>  X is a positive integer.

Comment: Why would it say "duplicate content deleted" instead of "plagiarized content deleted"? Since we have a concept of duplicate questions—and there's absolutely nothing wrong with those—we don't want to confuse people. Otherwise, I think I would support this. We need a no-tolerance policy for plagiarism, but it would also be more effective if it stung a bit.

Comment: I'd also make posts removed for plagiarism exempt from the >60 day >3 score rule for keeping reputation. This could be done independent of these changes.

Comment: -10 looks like a slap on the wrist to me. Maybe -50 or even -100 would make a better deterrent. Alternately, since often high-quality answers are being plagiarized, subtract from the perpetrator the amount of reputation gained by the original poster for their answer (granted, that can be *a bit* too much).

Comment: What motivated this post?

Comment: Are those all your posts that were plagiarized?  How do you find the plagiarizations?

Comment: Many of those posts are over a year old.  It would have been better if we'd caught them earlier.  And you do have to catch them.  Unless they are somehow flagged or brought to someone's attention, increasing the penalties is all for naught.

Comment: Hmm, a binding "abusive" vote imposes a 100 rep penalty.

Comment: @Robert Harvey: Except red flag deletions don't give users a chance to edit their posts to add attribution, etc.

Comment: The existing measures didn't seem effective enough, I checked with Tim in the Tavern, and his answer made me think about proposing a feasible solution

Comment: @Robert, wouldn't increased penalties at least curb the number of repeating offenders? In my experience, moderators seldom suspend these users on the first offense (you're nice like that). So at least two cycles of catching > flagging > retaliating are necessary.

Comment: I will never not be disturbed by the fact that a significant portion of people out there just don't *know* that plagiarism is wrong.

Comment: How would the user go about correcting the post and correctly attributing the content after the post was deleted? And would that correction also reverse the 100 rep penalty? It would seem like that would be needed so that the problem can be corrected and the user can learn.

Comment: Also one more thing to consider, when looking at two answers on SO where there is a question of plagiarism you don't always know where either user got their answers from. It is possible that user1 could have copied the answer from an external source created by user2. And if user2 later uses work from the external source they manage it might look like user2 copied user1's work when it was originally the other way around.

Comment: @Joe W: I imagine those situations will be taken into account if this feature makes it into implementation.

Comment: @Joe, when verifying, I personally always search for post excerpts on Google rather than SO to prevent this. In the eventuality (never happened so far) that both authors are plagiarizing, I would flag both posts. So far, I only found pure-external xor pure-internal occurrences, never a combination of both (but I'm not actively looking for these posts, so YMMV).

Comment: @JoeW: These steps are after it has been established as a case of plagiarism by mods and deleted. Attempts to salvage the post should happen 1) before flagging by user 2) flags should be declined by mods if post is salvagable. Plagiarism is established only if there is absolutely minimal or no original words by author.

Comment: @BoltClock I know an owner of a "successful" financial company that copies and pastes material from the web into her monthly letter. Doesn't see anything wrong with it, even after it was pointed out. Some people just don't get it.

Comment: Interestingly, earlier this week I flagged an answer which was clearly a verbatim copy of an old one. Guess what? My flag was declined. I even notified the person who posted the copy, to see if they would just delete the answer or at least mention the original poster.

Comment: How would a user who is post-banned be able to `work towards improving their content`? They're banned, right? So that paragraph sounds a lot like a `non-sequitor`. I also think that we need much better ways to find out what is plagiarism. I definitely would agree that word-for-word would be an easy case of plagiarism. But what about cases where it's not really plagiarism, but parallel conclusion?

Comment: See also: [Exact copies of an answer should be punished](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258040/456814).

Comment: @MelanciaUK: I just went to look at your flag, and I have to agree with whoever declined it - it's not a verbatim copy of any of the posts in the link you gave. Did you happen to paste the wrong link?

Comment: @BoltClock Thanks for looking at this. I did post the correct link, but maybe I was too "hard" in my words when saying it was a verbatim copy. If you look at the answer given by the user _lonesomeday_, you'll see that both are pretty, pretty similar.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion: you raise valid concerns. But as a self-sustaining community, I think that rather than rely on the mods to do all of our work, we should use the down-vote system against plagiarizing posts. A simple comment like "-1 for plagiarism" by a dozen or so members can be devastatingly effective - moreso than from a mod, IMHO.

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13261883/1709587) earned its 1750-rep 'author' a massive 870 dishonest rep that he will never lose. This irritates me. I am hugely in favour of stripping users of rep earned from plagiarism, and further penalties too.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

> However, in this process, the users don't get any immediate feedback, and may tend to continue borrowing other people's content without being aware that it is an incorrect practice, or consciously indulge in plagiarism in an attempt to gain reputation by copying highly-upvoted posts.

I can tell you that while it isn't obvious to regular users, we send mod messages to almost all people exhibiting patterns of plagiarism. Currently, that message reads like this:

> It has come to our attention that several of your answers consisted
>   primarily or entirely of text copied from other answers or websites.
>   We prefer not to simply copy content already available elsewhere in
>   lieu of creating something that adds value to this site
>   *specifically*.
>
> Whenever possible, we prefer that posts be your own original work, but
>   when a great answer already exists elsewhere, including a small
>   passage of text from another source can be a great way to support your
>   solution. But please note that **we require full attribution** with a
>   link to the original author, and please be sure you are ***not*
>   copying content without permission**.
>
> Thank you, and I look forward to your contributions in the future.

If they continue, we suspend their accounts. Simply being warned about it causes almost all plagiarists to stop, with many apologizing.

I don't think imposing harsher penalties will act as a deterrent, because most plagiarists don't even realize it's a problem, or are the kind who wouldn't keep up with the rules of the site to know that we had such a punishment. Even if all we do is delete their answers and warn them, the message does seem to be received.

Our big problem is early detection of plagiarism, not enforcement once detected. We appreciate the work that some users have been doing in tracking down difficult-to-find instances of this, because it's always a chore to separate really good answers that are new from really good answers that are copied from somewhere else. Proposed solutions for this (matching against all previously left answers on the site to identify duplicates) unfortunately don't scale to a site the size of Stack Overflow, but maybe there are better ways of finding this content earlier.

Comment: May I gently suggest that, if an offense warrants a mod message, it also warrants a suspension?  The first offense is only 7 days.  Many users who get mod messages without a suspension simply ignore them, or respond with "f*ck you, I'll do what I want."  The suspension adds some consequences.

Comment: I've also been commenting on posts that I delete for plagiarism, so even if a user isn't exhibiting rampant bad behavior they're getting a note in their inbox.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - For plagiarism, my experience has been that the vast majority read these messages and take them to heart, without the need for account suspension. Many simply don't know that what they've done is wrong, due to different cultural norms. I've even had surprisingly good results from messaging, but not suspending, those who commit a first offense of voting fraud. My goal is behavioral change, more than punishment.

Comment: I agree with you about behavioral changes. So I replaced 100 with X, even -1 rep(which is less than a downvote on bad content) is fine, if it helps to prevent/discourage the behaviour in future. The old posts will be cleaned sooner or later, but new ones need to be prevented.

Comment: I guess this is a losing battle if you need to do this manually, just by the sheer numbers of posts you'd need to check. Anyone serious about making this a priority, needs to think about automating the detection. There's tools (http://mashable.com/2012/08/29/plagiarism-online-services/), but I guess there's also budget (time and $). The latter will probably dictate the priority.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Are you kidding?  Do users really respond with "___k you" messages to moderators?

Comment: @BradLarson To improve the current solution of detection we'd need what's being done at the moment

Comment: This post gets my +1. A highly balanced, *moderate* approach to the problem.

Comment: @0xdeadbeef About half of them respond with some form of either "it was the other guy's fault" or "you can't tell me what to do."  That shouldn't be a surprise, really; pros don't get mod messaged.

Comment: @0xdeadbeef: To be fair, Brad puts more effort into reforming people than I do (read: being nice). I personally have had better success with communications that come with some... erm, "corrective action," as my words seem to have no effect on folks without it.  I feel that  my role as a moderator is to stop the bad behavior first (which the suspension does quite effectively) and then educate (for which I think Meta is better suited).

Comment: @FooBar - For detection on the SE side, there really isn't any. Moderators deal with it as we or other users come across it, but there's nothing in the system at present to proactively discover it. As I mentioned, the suggestions that have been provided for this do not scale to a site the size of Stack Overflow, so something that could work here would need to be identified first. I don't even know if it's worth the effort to build such a system, given how relatively infrequent plagiarism is. Thousands of plagiarized posts might seem like a huge problem, but that's among 14 million answers.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I wish that some bit of common sense was more common in the world.  Needless to say, you guys put in a lot of effort -- in _educating_ users and everything else.  Of course, I've seen quite a bit of Brad's posts and those are pretty enlightening.  Keep up the good work.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: To be honest I would agree with you if Brad's approach wasn't working. But he says it is, so I feel like it's not necessary to add extra punishment.

Comment: @BradLarson Seems like a case of ignorance to the rules. Perhaps implement plagiarism into the intro/rule page (if it isn't already) or notify newbies before plagiarism is ever committed. A lot of it seems to happen quite a while after the original post so plagiarism is difficult to catch. For verbatim copies [I've had this happen] maybe implement a small "check" when a new post is made. Doesn't seem too difficult to do. How prevalent is plagiarism on SO?