# Shouldn't there be an option to close a question if they are college related?

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close

I believe stackOverFlow is getting flooded by college students that feel that their assignments can be done by others by just posting it in stackOverFlow. Unfortunately I've seen it over and over again that they get answered.

I feel its very bad:

1. The students won't do their homework thus won't learn anything, as they don't even try to solve the problem. not even bother to search for it.
2. questions quality are getting lower.
3. many more reasons...

I propose to add a flag to be able to close such questions specifically. (e.g. reason for being assignment based)

Students should answer their own questions, that's the only thing that they need to do.

I feel its opinion based but Am I not right?

Comment: If the question is well asked, we won't know it's a college student asking anyway. The fact that it's an assignment shouldn't be a close reason.

Comment: related [http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253792/stack-overflow-and-homework-questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253792/stack-overflow-and-homework-questions)

Comment: @KevinB true, atleast those are clever enough to not show its a assignment. but there are some that are well obvious

Comment: downvote it to oblivion, and they'll eventually lose their ability to ask.

Comment: @KevinB I do but they are getting answers. I feel bad about students more than anyone really.

Comment: I don't think adding a new close reason would change that. Look at how many closed questions have answers now.

Comment: _"I"m working on a project for my college course, and my teacher has given us X requirement. Now I figured out how to do this with Y instead, but when I try to rearrange the code to work with X I get Z error. I tried A, B, C, and D to fix the error, but none of these have worked. What else can I do to resolve this issue?"_ Boom. Good college homework question. So due to this, admittedly rare, occurrence of a _good_ homework question, we shouldn't _blanket_ exclude homework questions. Yes, the X requirement will likely be stupid, but there are companies that have seemingly stupid restrictions.

Comment: I downCloseVote most of them anyway 'cos no inputs, no outputs, no error messages, no warnings, no exception messages, no progress messages, no testing, no debugging  and general cluelessness.  It would be nice if it was possible to apply 10 downvotes for those homework questions that are disguised, but I can live without that.

Comment: I got some upvotes and an accept for suggesting that students get paid for exposing their disreputable colleagues: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10313474/758133

Answer (score 6):

> 1. The students won't do their homework thus won't learn anything, as they don't even try to solve the problem. not even bother to search for it.

This is a problem with professionals who don't research anything and hobbyists as well. Self debugging is as important to those groups as much as it is to students

> questions quality are getting lower.

It seems that way often. Though this isn't only do to students. I know quite a few students who research and ask very good questions.

> many more reasons...

very insightful

> Students should answer their own questions, that's the only thing that they need to do.

Then you, as a professional (I'm assuming) should answer all of your problems for work, hobby, whatever because that is all you need to do...finish the tasks assigned to you.

A bad question is a bad question no matter who asks it. Same for a good question.

Also, there are enough close reasons that more specifically relate to these bad questions. Use those. People will have a much better idea of what they did wrong on the site if you close it as "too broad", "unclear", etc... than if you say, "This question should be closed because you're a student. Do your own damn work"

Comment: I have taught in University level. we have been discussion with other lecturers to monitor stackoverflow to find out which of the students get their answers directly from it (believe me its true) for plagiarism purposes. (continue)

Comment: moreover  90%+ of questions are related to lecture notes or suggested books. they need to do X based on Y topics that they have been taught. Of course there are better way of doing things as they have been told, but they need to do it as they've been told because there is a good reason for it. Also you should know job of a student is just to learn while professional have (on top of learning ofcourse)  to do the job .

Comment: *"for plagiarism purposes"* I don't blame you for trying to cut down on that but that should not be the job of SO. Your question does not say anything about that statement. *"moreover 90%+ of questions are related to lecture notes or suggested books"* then those questions will be closed for other reasons as stated in my answer. *"Also you should know job of a student is just to learn"* I understand that but if they are stuck on something then why shouldn't they use available resources to help them learn as they will do when they leave the university?

Comment: btw, based on our university (unfortunately not sure if it can be named) the number of requests to stackOverFlow from student's designated computers have had 700% increase in the last 3 years

Comment: @nafas Worth reading [Should I send students to Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254433/should-i-send-students-to-stack-overflow)

Comment: I don't see that as anything but a positive thing as long as they are using the site correctly. I've learned more from asking/answering questions on SO than I did from college. From what I am reading, you may consider spending time teaching students how to properly use these external resources, including SO. That's not meant to be nasty but SO, along with many others, is a great resource for learning (used properly, of course).

Comment: @nafas - we've noticed.  I especially take exception to those who want already-freely-available information rewritten by SO contributors so as to generate new, unique copypasta that will be deleted if answered, not match any other submissions and avoid anti-plagiarism scripts.

Comment: @nafas - The extra traffic may have to do with the fact that the google page rankings for SO have gone up significantly in the past few years. From a plagiarism perspective, [Bob](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306187/how-can-sede-be-utilized-to-find-potential-plagiarism-on-stack-overflow) probably has more insight. And as far as student questions go, most of us here on meta are aware of what student questions look like and avoid spoon feeding the answer with complete code.