# You get to keep reputation from plagiarized posts if they aren't discovered within 60 days

Tags: feature-request, reputation, plagiarism

If I amass a huge amount of reputation through plagiarized answers, and someone discovers it a year later, and moderators delete the answers, I get to keep the reputation gained through those answers (under the rule of [reputation not being removed for deleted contributions older than 60 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222)).

That seems... wrong.

If there's no reputation loss, there's really no deterrent against plagiarism at all (except maybe in those rare cases where literally the entire account consists of plagiarism and is nuked by the moderators).

You just need to go undetected for two months, which is not hard.

This makes looking for plagiarized contributions (or even caring about plagiarism on the sites at all) basically pointless - and consequently, Stack Overflow reputation becomes even more meaningless than it already is.

Comment: Destroy the user, their posts and their reputation on the second offense. Problem solved.

Comment: If the deletion of plagiarized content gets the user a post-ban, it is still effective, even if the user gets to keep their ill-gotten points.

Comment: This is actually a valid point. If someone plagiarized something with a certain no. of points and got away with it for 2 months, there isn't a way to take that rep from them. Huh. Maybe that's something that needs fixing.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi the mods don't seem to do that if there's original content on the account, too. Only in cases of 100% plagiarism

Comment: @Pekka, yup, it makes sense that moderators prefer to err on the side of indulgence. But personally, when I think about it I consider plagiarism as the worst kind of offense one can inflict to the network. Voting rings and sockpuppets are a joke compared to plagiarism, which allows one user to take credit for another's efforts. I would let it pass once (to err is human) but not twice.

Comment: @Pekka웃 you're right in the sense that if someone makes a genuine attempt to help that happens to be plagiarism - we'll just delete the post and give the user a nudge. If it's a blatant plagiarist - their account goes boom anyway. Also - although moderators don't have the ability to, we have a way of contacting the community team and can request vote invalidation. So basically - as soon as it's realised - action can be taken one way or t'other.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234022/plagiarism-is-a-good-way-to-earn-reputation-combatting-this-after-the-fact

Comment: We've had community managers disassociate highly upvoted stolen content from the filthy thieves who posted them from time to time. I wonder if it'd be worth reporting them using flags or the contact form...

Comment: @JonClements I recently flagged a number of contributions from someone who was both a blatant plagiarist, but also kind of a helpful community member in other posts. Nuking the account seems extreme, but letting them keep the rep from their plagiarism is wrong, too.  I flagged only five examples, should I flag everything I can find so other measures (like  getting a team member to invalidate the votes) is considered?

Comment: Also @BoltClock

Comment: @Pekka웃 there's a bit more to do but this specific case is handled.

Comment: Oh, come on Pekka, do we have to have yet another discussion about what reputation actually means??   Yet again: it is not a number that has anything to do with technical competence, only how familiar you are with the system.  Given the completely hypothetical case of somebody that earns lots of rep with plagiarized content and not getting noticed for an entire year, surely you ought to vote for him in the next moderator election.  That's a *very* smart operator that knows every trick in the book.  Besides, it is *just* hypothetical, the community police won't let it happen.

Comment: @Hans `Given the completely hypothetical case of somebody that earns lots of rep with plagiarized content and not getting noticed for an entire year, surely you ought to vote for him in the next moderator election.` that indeed puts a completely different perspective on it!...  :) Any similarities with any currently running real-world elections are entirely coincidental, of course.

Comment: Just for the record though, those cases aren't hypothetical, and the community police doesn't seem to be great at catching serial plagiarists. I frequently run into years-old contributions where a guy  with broken English suddenly writes like a MIT grad. @Hans

Comment: You know what is worse? The plagiarized content getting more upvotes than the original one. I cam across a post where the whole answer was copied from another answer and had a comment below stating something like *I copied all this stuff from the other answer <link>.*. The other answer did not even have half of the upvotes of the plagiarized answer. (Aside, One of the projects at [Sobotics](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/111347/sobotics) room, is to detect plagiarized posts, to prevent this from happening again. But, Thanks to paid software, the project hasn't seen much progress).

Comment: @Bhargav Rao: maybe we should extend the feature request to that positive reputation gained through plagiarism should not get removed, but redirected to the original post, if it is on Stack Exchange… (minus the votes made by someone who voted both answers).

Comment: [I'm with you](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269315/changes-to-discourage-plagiarism#comment264724_269315), Pekka, but [Brad Larson, at least, isn't](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269319/1709587). I'm not sure how much the mod team shares our view that plagiarism needs to be more robustly deterred via the rep system (and that, any deterrent effect aside, the rep from plagiarised posts should be removed as a matter of justice and of keeping the rep system meaningful), rather than plagiarism just cleaned up and verbally warned against.

Comment: I don't read that as Brad disagreeing with Pekka's request. I mean, he might, but that post doesn't say so. Brad is arguing against the *deterrent effect* justification for adding harsher punishments for plagiarism. Like crime in the real world, deterrence is known to be ineffective, no matter how much it *seems* like harsh penalties should create a deterrent effect. But there is good reason to remove reputation for plagiarized answers that goes far beyond false hope of a deterrent effect. As Pekka points out, it devalues the reputation system. (If it already meaningless, as Hans is arguing.)

Comment: Why does it matter what happens to reputation? How does the plagiarised content hurt the site or it's uses? If a question is answered with plagiarised content is this better or worse than an unanswered question?
In an ideal world the OP would have searched better, less than ideal someone comes along and links questions.

Comment: @ShiftyThomas: "How does the plagiarised content hurt the site or it's uses?" It does so by undermining the original content creators. There is no excuse for answering a question without giving credit where credit is due - there is nothing preventing one from doing both at the same time.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To start off, this doesn't actually happen all that often which makes it hard to justify implementing automated systems to fight this. In most cases, plagiarism never attracts a huge mass of votes, or the user is also involved in some sort of voting fraud that causes the post scores to drop back below thresholds (or at least to the point where I can downvote it and not worry about reputation anymore).

When this *does* happen in those rare instances, it's still easy to fix by just disassociating the post. Since the user doesn't exactly "own" the post in any way - it's just a copy paste of *someone else's* text - it's fairly easy to justify removing the post from their account. Upon doing so, their reputation is instantly recalculated to exclude the post. (Don't worry, we log that the post used to belong to them in several places.)

I've personally only had to do this three times in the two years I've worked here, but I'd encourage any moderators who see a highly voted post deleted as plagiarism (after the 60 days of course) to reach out to us to have it removed from their account as part of the process. Because you're right, letting them keep large masses of reputation for what is essentially a form of cheating isn't a very strong deterrent in preventing them from doing it again in the future, and it literally takes us like 5 seconds to fix.

Comment: The bad news is that this doesn't show up as a demerit in the offending user's reputation history. The good news is that this doesn't show up as a demerit in the offending user's reputation history. In case anyone is wondering...