# Meta, I have a problem. Should I call for you or is a moderator flag enough?

Tags: discussion, answers, plagiarism

While cruising the suggested edits queue, I arrived at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18143654/5292302)

[image: screenshot]

So what's the problem (let's leave aside that it's answering how to add 1 day and not 1 month as asked in the question (that's a downvote/upvote reason) and people like it a lot, so I guess they have a strange calendar or was searching for something else).

It also has copied code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9613729/5292302) (see the `addDays` function) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/428966/5292302) see the bottom code.

OP has left a link, it's old, with lots of upvotes (so is it useful?). Let me consider it's in good faith and I can edit to add the correct attribution, but what do I end up with?

The quoted answer on how to add 1 day on a question that asks how to add 1 month with lots of upvotes, hmm that's a duplicate, but the question is not a duplicate (the days in a month are not always the same at least, not in my calendar).

I actually then decided to leave a comment on the question (related) and raise a custom moderator flag.

However, what do I do if a moderator comes by and decides to just add attribution, which seems the most obvious thing do to if you do not have domain knowledge and take a lot time to study the posts (moderator trap). I retracted and decided to cry out for your help on Meta.

Was I correct to gather a >20K <s>mob</s> "cloud of experts" on Meta to delete it? What should I do in this situation? Is it better to bring to Meta or just let moderators handle it? (And if they don't choose what I think is correct, I post a "Who declined my flag?" on Meta?)

Comment: What really drives me bonkers is that it has so many upvotes, being just a wrong answer that was posted 2.5 years after the fact. What the heck people :/

Comment: A mod flag with "plagiarized from x and y" tends to get things removed.

Comment: @PaulCrovella to me the problem was that it is old and actually have a link to the question, hence in good faith I see it as "incorrect attribution" that I can fix. However I will not deny that I just like it to get deleted! (and since I'm still plep I can't vote for that), internet is a better place without that (my comment under question is enough, for misguided search result)

Comment: *it would have been fun to raise a NAA flag*, since maybe it would be correct (it's not answering the question, and link pointing to other question should be a comment)

Comment: A lot of plagiarism happens in good faith surprisingly enough. Many folk don't understand why it's an issue and are trying to help in their misguided way. If a mod decides to correct the attribution rather than remove it that's up to them - I've only seen it happen rarely and will likely depend which mod handles the flag.

Comment: @Cody (I can't ping you), I know you solved the issue, but your answer was still interesting since my question is if it's better to mod flag or invoke "cloud of experts"

Comment: I'm considering rewriting it... May not happen right away. I don't want to send the wrong impression in the meantime.

Comment: @Gimby maybe those aren't real votes?   i can't see that many people finding it much less upvoting it.

Comment: @snb I hope so actually, but it may also just be lemming-voting...

Comment: @Cody Gray: As a moderator, sending the wrong impression is *in our blood* (diamonds).

Comment: This is on hot meta posts now. Upvote if you came here expecting a generic question only to be disappointed by a question specific to plagiarism.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Plagiarism should **always** be handled by a moderator<sup>1</sup>, as it is [fundamentally a behavioral issue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299777/what-should-be-done-with-users-found-guilty-of-plagiarism/299784#299784) more than simply a content issue, much like targeted voting, sock puppet use, and rudeness. For some users, this is a one-off issue, but for others, this can be a pattern, making it a much more serious problem. Moderators have the tools to enforce this and reach out to users to address it in ways that regular users do not. Furthermore, we decline enough false plagiarism accusations on a regular basis that we simply cannot trust regular users to [moderate these issues on our behalf](http://www.newgrounds.com/bbs/topic/588210#bbspost10639310_post_text).

You can still get involved by

- leaving a comment for the benefit of others to indicate that the answer you found contains plagiarism, *with a link to the original source*, and
- voting to close the question as a duplicate in the case of content copied from answers to duplicate questions

but I'd urge you to leave the corrective action to us, as again, plagiarism can often be a sign of deeper behavioral issues (sometimes not limited to plagiarism) that only a moderator has the tools and the judgement to investigate and deal with *on a case-by-case basis*. Some flaggers will help us find out if a user has a pattern of plagiarism and inform us within the flag, but if going through someone's profile makes you uncomfortable (for all the good reasons), leave it to us, we'll do it anyway.

(Yes, 99% of the time an answer that consists of stolen content is deleted without hesitation; I've personally had *limited* success with editing attribution into other people's answers — not even complete as I've had at least one incident of a user *rolling back* my edits, effectively sending the message that they were acting in bad faith — and I've always maintained that [the responsibility falls on the user to ensure that anything they copy is attributed and meets Fair Use](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321299/answers-entirely-copied-though-properly-attributed/321326#321326).)

Plus, only moderators have a direct channel with the community team to ask for stolen content to be disassociated, [effectively removing all their ill-gotten rep from an account](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336392/you-get-to-keep-reputation-from-plagiarized-posts-if-they-arent-discovered-with/345460#345460), in the case of answers that will survive rep changes getting reversed on deletion such as the one you link to.

As always, if you disagree with a moderator's decision, you are free to either reflag or bring it up on meta. But in the case of plagiarism, I don't recommend trying to overrule a moderator's decision unless they've acknowledged that they were in the wrong (in which case they probably would have reversed their actions already).

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>At least, on Stack Overflow; [different advice seems to exist for other sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160071/what-to-do-when-plagiarism-is-discovered/160072#160072).</sub>

Comment: What do you think we should do with meta [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160071/what-to-do-when-plagiarism-is-discovered/160072#160072)?, edit it to included this information. *"On SO if you find it, flag it, no editing"*

Comment: @Petter Friberg: I can't answer that.