# How close does an "exact" answer duplicate need to be, to be automatically flagged?

Tags: discussion, flags, duplicate-answers

This comes off of the back of the accepted answer on the question [Exact copies of an answer should be punished](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258048/3484879). Specifically, what I'm asking is "Does the answer have to *literally* be an exact copy for the system to automatically flag?", or does it have some small amount of leeway.

To make an example. Let's say someone has a answer like this:

> You can use `COALESCE` to return a different column's value, if the
>   first has the value `NULL`:
>
> ```
> COALESCE(CustomerName,CompanyName)
> ```

Then, on a different question (could be some time later, months/years), the **same** user posts the below answer:

> You can use `COALESCE` to return a different column's value, if the
>   first has the value `NULL`:
>
> ```
> COALESCE(HomeNumber,MobileNumber)
> ```

Would that latter answer be automatically flagged? Also, if it isn't automatically flagged, *should* it be (either automatically or by a user)?

Would your answer to *should* it change if the question the second answer is posted on is closed as a duplicate of the question which has the first answer (upvoted or accepted) in it? If not, does your opinion change if the user who posted said answers is a "gold badger" in the respective tags?

Comment: I guess it need to be *exact copy* because I found a lot of such *slightly changed* answer and when I flag them they are deleted by Moderators

Comment: Honestly, with that example, the question should be marked as a duplicate and quite possibly deleted. It's not unimaginable the user forgot the first one, and wrote the second identical one from scratch because the answer is incredibly basic.

Comment: [An](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17586/best-word-wrap-algorithm/15700233#15700233) [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253890/how-to-wrap-a-very-long-word/15700667#15700667) (and plagiarised code).

Comment: @PeterMortensen this isn't about plagiarism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a moderator judgment question, and there are a few factors I would take into account when I was a moderator:

1. How new the user was. If the user was really new, then they didn't realize this behavior was "not cool", and so I'd go further down the checklist.
2. Are the questions duplicates? That is, could I close and merge one question into the other and the same meaning would be conveyed and the answers would apply equally? If so, I'd close and merge the lower views, votes, answer # into the higher one, using criteria I've set out before.
3. If the questions are not duplicates, and the answers are tailored to the question asked, then I'd leave it be.
4. If the questions are not duplicates, but the answer *is an exact copy* of a previous answer the poster has posted to another question, I'd leave a comment and delete the answer.
5. If the answer is not an exact copy, and the question is not a duplicate, then I'd move on.  That's a case for downvoting (or upvoting, or community cleanup), not moderator cleanup.

Moderators are exception handlers. I would tend to allow for and ensure the community took agency for non-clearcut examples of something that needed moderator attention. That way, the community takes responsibliity for its own actions, and doesn't try to push everything on to the moderators (there were only 20 or so; 20 people do not scale).

In the case you mention, it's impossible to tell from the answer itself whether the questions are duplicates, and therefore it would be handled situationally based on the questions these answers came from.

Comment: Thanks George, this is really detailed. I did intentionally leave out a real world example, as I dislike drawing attention to quesions/answers that aren't my own; a voting band wagon can be far too common and I wouldn't want that on someone (regardless of if they are a gold badger or new contributor). This does cover all the scenarios, which is great, and does make me think I should probably flag some answers in the past I haven't. I won't mark as the solution yet, to see if there's any other contributions. I *assume* your answer implies the system only marks literal *exact* duplicates too?

Comment: @larnu That's right. Only exact text duplicates are flagged by the system.