# Should we be allowed to flag duplicate answers?

Tags: discussion, answers, flags, duplicate-answers

This has been one of my pet peeves for quite some time now -- duplicate answers in the same question. I know almost everyone has encountered this at least once, in their answers, questions, or even when browsing through posts.

Duplicate answers are answers in the same question that are functionally the same as another answer in that question. The most common case I'd see would be more `if-else` block, `switch-case` statements, a longer more readable code (maybe expanding 1 lines to 2 lines), some are even flat out copy pasted ones.

The reason why I want to be able the community to flag duplicate answers is that duplicates very rarely add anything new to the discussion. And the thing is that there are other members who choose to comment instead in order to clarify the existing answer instead of adding their own as a way to further discussion.

I know that a good number of our members want those easy upvotes (since sometimes OP feels the need to upvote both but only accept one because they're functionally the same), but it's rather dismaying if those +reps are gained through essentially copy pasted expanded answers that contribute nothing to the discussion, making their rep count a misleading metric on how much they've truly contributed to the site.

While I concede that duplicate answers harm no one, since it harms no one, it shouldn't also be a problem to be able to flag and remove them.

Comment: related: [Vote to delete answers as duplicates of earlier answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243243/165773)

Comment: If they are near identical answers to another or have clearly been taken from someone elses answer, you can flag it as a moderator flag as plagiarism. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251022/3270037

Comment: Why would you assume that the only reason for duplicate answers is people wanting easy upvotes?

Comment: For easy questions it's very easy to come up with practically the same answer *at the same time*. How do you choose between 2 answer posted at the same minute with the same contents? Who should "win"? A different matter are answers posted days/weeks/months afterwards that just repeat existing content: downvote those.

Comment: Re "While I concede that duplicate answers harm no one [...]": duplicate answer waste *every reader*'s time while they go through answers trying to find the one that best matches their question and is most current. For popular questions, there are many outdated answers, and new, better ones, struggle to get enough votes to bubble to the top. Duplicate answers only make that process harder by taking away attention and upvotes. @gnat explained that [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/243271/150034).

Answer (score 53):

The problem with flagging is, unless they're literally copy-paste duplicates of an existing answer, you need to have some technical knowledge in the relevant technology to be able to determine whether the additional answer adds value or not. That means you can't ask moderators to make the judgment, first because we don't (and can't) have moderators who are experts on all technologies discussed on this site, and second because assessing technical validity just isn't a moderator's job.

(If you see answers that are copy-paste or otherwise *blindingly obvious* duplicates of existing answers, then flag flag flag away. Use the custom "needs moderator attention" flag and explain your concerns. Moderators *will* deal with these obvious cases of outright plagiarism.)

Instead, you need a trusted community member to make this judgment—someone who has demonstrated their knowledge of the relevant technology (by posting answers that get upvotes and thus accumulate reputation). It turns out that the system does kind of support this by way of granting *delete* votes to trusted users. [At 20k+ reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user), users can vote to delete downvoted answers (those with a score of −1 or below). After 3 such votes have been cast, the answer is deleted.

This *does* work in practice. A single downvote and a single delete vote from a trusted user dumps the question in a queue, accessible via the "Review" page, that other users with the "trusted user" privilege can use to view, evaluate, and cast their own delete votes. And even outside of the queue, on popular questions, experts who arrive at the question and see the low-quality answers will also see that delete votes have been cast, and can add one of their own, too.

There are two primary problems with this system:

1. There really aren't enough 20k+ users to handle the load.

   I'm not sure how you solve this problem other than extending the vote-to-delete franchise to users at lower reputation levels. This might work, especially if we weighted their votes differently. For example, right now it takes 3 votes from 20k+ users to cause an answer to be deleted. We can say that their votes are individually worth −1 unit. Then, we could allow 10k+ users to cast delete votes on answers that would be worth −½ units. That should be sufficient; we have quite a few 10k+ users, and since 10k+ users already have access to other moderation tools, including the ability to vote to delete questions (at least, questions that have been closed for 48 hours), it wouldn't be that crazy for them to have the power to vote to delete answers, too.
2. There isn't a good way for users with the requisite privileges to *find* the answers that might merit deletion.

   I mentioned above that there is a "delete votes" queue in the reviewing tools, but this lists *all* posts with delete votes, and for things like this that require domain knowledge, that makes it hard to find the ones you are most qualified to evaluate. It would be nice if we could *filter* these low-quality answers by tag. I guess the idea I'm throwing out is a bit like another review queue for answers that, while they fit the minimal threshold for an answer, are not actually adding value and should be removed. The problem with this suggestion, of course, is…SRSLY? *Another* queue? Who wants to wade through *more crap*? Indeed, who? There is already so much crap that needs to be reviewed, most of it far more harmful than a duplicate answer, and thus the limited human capital that we have available is best focused on these more significant quality problems.

My *personal* favorite solution would be to give gold tag badge holders more privileges. Extend Mjölnir's powers to instantly delete a downvoted answer on a question tagged with a tag where you holds gold tag badge, with the same caveats as before, namely that you cannot be the person who added the tag for which you hold the badge, and additionally perhaps that yours cannot be the sole downvote (this reigns in the power a bit, without severely hampering it because *tons* of people have downvote privileges).

I honestly think that extending the power of gold tag badge holders is the best solution available to a lot of our quality problems. I think the granting of insta-dupe-closure privileges to these users has been a *resounding success*, far beyond anyone's wildest dreams, and that they have proven themselves highly trustworthy. They should have more powers to close questions for other reasons (especially the other "off topic" reasons), and they should have more powers to delete *ostensibly* valid but useless answers that moderators cannot and will not handle. I haven't seen much evidence, though, that anyone on the Stack Exchange team is interested in doing this.

In the meantime, the best you can do is downvote these answers. Once extensively downvoted, hopefully the person who posted them will be motivated to delete them. At worst, they'll be grayed out on the page and the garbage will be better hidden.

(Why do I not think downvoting alone is sufficient? Well, beyond the fact that garbage should be *removed*, rather than merely hidden—imagine a trash can that you never emptied—as observed in the question, there are a lot of <strike>new</strike> users who only care about reputation, aren't concerned with the overall quality of the site, and will continue posting these answers. It takes motivated, conscientious users to cancel out this effect, and we are vastly outnumbered. We need better tools.)

Comment: On solution might be that only 20k users can make the first deletion vote but afterwards everybody with >5k can make the other two votes?

Comment: The delete vote doesn't really push the question into a queue accessible by review though. The moderator tools only show part of the answers with recent delete votes, and that's about it.

Comment: That's what I'm talking about, @tunaki. Maybe "review" was the wrong word, since it does imply those queues. The list is part of [the 10k tools](http://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=delete&daterange=today).

Comment: What about giving gold badge people the ability to delete as you suggested, then also allowing other users to flag, and a flagged answer goes to a special queue where tag gold badge holders can only review questions with their tag.

Comment: @the It's not an unreasonable suggestion, but: "The problem with this suggestion, of course, is…SRSLY? Another queue? Who wants to wade through more crap? Indeed, who? There is already so much crap that needs to be reviewed, most of it far more harmful than a duplicate answer, and thus the limited human capital that we have available is best focused on these more significant quality problems." I believe it would be better if the users who come across it naturally can deal with it immediately. There's no real need to shove it into their faces with a queue.

Comment: @CodyGray: Agree with extended powers based on badges, rather than raw reputation (or in conjunction). I've got about as much reputation and as you, so I can vote, but let's be honest there are plenty of technologies where I don't know much, or anything at all.

Comment: Unless there's another queue I'm unaware of - users below 20k (not sure what the limit is) can [see and vote to delete answers](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts). I'm unsure if a delete vote pushes it into this queue, or if this queue is only based on an automatic heuristic. Granted, below 20k one can only 'recommend deletion' which is somewhat less powerful than a 'delete' vote from a 20k+ user. This seems inline with your suggestion to have 'half votes' from 10k+ users.

Comment: @rob That assumes the post is in the "Low Quality" queue, and flagging a post as "low quality" to get it there is dangerous because moderators also review that queue and they have a *very* different definition of "low quality" than presumably you or I do. In particular, an answer that is useless because it repeats what other answers already say will *not* be considered "low quality" by a moderator because, taken out of context, it looks like a valid answer. So no, that's not a general solution. But yes, they do get "recommend deletion" votes, which are akin to what I'm proposing.

Comment: @CodyGray Fair enough, I was under the impression a delete vote pushes the post into that queue. Though granted, I rarely visit that queue anyway.

Comment: No, a delete vote doesn't put the post in that queue. Only a "very low quality" flag. Delete votes *will* land the post in [this list](http://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=delete&daterange=today), which I linked to in an earlier comment, which anyone with 10k+ reputation can see. @rob

Comment: What about giving different levels of voting to different badge holders, e.g. gold tag badge has hammer, silver gets to vote, bronze gets 1/2 of a vote.

Comment: So, the status quo for technically identical answers is _"Down-vote. Delete-vote if 20k+. Do not flag for moderators unless literal plagiarism."_ Am I reading that right? I want to make sure I'm doing the right thing for now while I hope for the glorious future.

Comment: Yes, that's unfortunately correct, @Michael. I mean, you can flag them with a custom moderator flag if you want and explain the problem, but that relies on a moderator who is (A) competent, and (B) willing to use their brain. I've had some degree of success with this, especially in cases where I can argue that the presence of the answer is actually making the Internet worse, but mileage varies.

Comment: @Michael: There's a 3rd problem with this system: functionally/technically identical answers that the masses have upvoted, so there's no practical way to bring them to -1. I wrote more about this in [my answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/386688/1269037).

Comment: @DanDascalescu See [related](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355137/interesting-undownvoted-occurrence-on-my-account/355138#comment504861_355138).

Answer (score 6):

I keep seeing duplicate answers that are essentially the same as other, older, and more upvoted answers. The only difference is that the duplicator hasn't bothered to give as good of an explanation; often the answer is just the same piece of code with variables changed. Here's an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7811163/query-for-documents-where-array-size-is-greater-than-1/40123920#40123920):

```js
db.getCollection('collectionName').find({'ArrayName.1': {$exists: true}})
```

vs. the better written and explained answer given [3 years earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7811163/query-for-documents-where-array-size-is-greater-than-1/15224544#15224544) and containing:

```js
db.accommodations.find({'name.1': {$exists: true}})
```

All the variables are placeholders. `accommodations` is made up. There's no functional difference between the answers. The newer, duplicate one, doesn't offer absolutely anything in addition.

Now I'm not assuming plagiarism; rather, carelessness on the part of the answerers, and on the part of the upvoters who didn't realize (or care) that the answer had already been given. Still, these answers waste everyone's time, and I would love it if there was a flag for them.

I have 20k+ rep, but I'm still powerless. My downvote and comment won't do anything. I've commented on at least 20+ such answers over the last month, and *nobody* has ever acknowledged that, "Hey, I didn't see it when I posted, thanks for letting me know, I'll remove it". As @CodyGrey mentioned, some users care more about reputation than about quality. It often works. In the example above: 33 upvotes at the time of writing, for a dupe answer. *Mine was the **only** downvote.*

I've also flagged a few for moderator attention, mentioning they were repeat answers, and my flags were denied.

Comment: I have also had this issue recently. Going through the review queues and flagging duplicate answers is a great way to get a 7-day ban. Makes me wonder why I bother with it, to be honest.