# Are trivial variations of code acceptable answers?

Tags: discussion, answers, duplicate-answers

A user in the PowerShell tag seems to have picked up the habit of posting trivial code variations of existing answers.

Examples:

- if an existing answer suggests a `Where-Object` filter

  ```
  ... | Where-Object { $_ -eq 'foo' } | ...
  ```

  he would suggest a `ForEach-Object` loop with a nested `if` statement

  ```
  ... | ForEach-Object { if ($_ -like 'foo') { $_ } } | ...
  ```
- if an existing answer used calculated properties

  ```
  ... | Select-Object @{n='foo';e={$_.Size / 1GB}}
  ```

  he would suggest a building custom objects in a loop:

  ```
  ... | ForEach-Object {
      [PSCustomObject]@{
          'foo' = $_.Size / 1GB
      }
  }
  ```

In each case the semantic of both statements is the same, even though the syntax differs.

To me this feels like a cheap rip-off, even though it's not flat-out plagiarism. More so, since the answers usually contain little to no explanation.

What is the community consensus on this kind of answer? Do we tolerate them? Downvote? Flag as low quality? Flag for moderator attention?

Comment: `even though it's not flat-out plagiarism` If they're creating a derived work of another answer and not citing it, it *is* plagiarism.  If they're independantly arriving at a similar solution without realizing that there's another similar answer, *then* it's not plagiarism.

Comment: For starters, from what you've described, the answers *aren't useful*, so you can start by downvoting them.  Whether they merit a mod flag is going to depend on whether it actually ends up being plagiarism, which is hard to say conclusively given the information provided.

Comment: Doing it on old answers? No explanation or cleanup on old answers? Any added value at all? If all of that is yes, seems like he's just trying to siphon reputation

Comment: Probably related https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342211/should-we-be-allowed-to-flag-duplicate-answers

Comment: Also curious if you know of a way to achieve those alternative answers from an automated refactoring tool

Comment: @GeekyI The answers are usually posted to recent questions AFAICS. The only added value I can see is that the answers shows a slightly different way to the same end. As for automated refactoring, I haven't looked into that, so I can't tell. Might be possible, but like I said, the changes are trivial modifications that I would consider obvious to anyone with at least a basic understanding of PowerShell.

Comment: Are they really trivial variations? Lots of times there are multiple ways to solve a problem and we're trying to build a base of answers that work for more than one person. Maybe the alternative would work for someone not familiar with the original answer.

Comment: @bluefeet In my eyes they are. But of course my view might be biased, which is part of why I posted the question. Take for instance the first example: a `Where-Object` filter basically takes each input item, checks it against a condition, and passes or discards the item depending on the result. The `ForEach-Object`/`if` combination does effectively the same.

Comment: In the context of active new questions, this isn't anything new. In fact, on some intentionally unnamed tags such an occurrence is commonplace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vote on the answers based on their usefulness as deemed by you. The usual voting guidelines apply: if you're sure they are low quality or otherwise not helpful (as you state that the answers usually contain little to no explanation), downvote; if you believe they somehow add value, upvote; if in doubt, abstain from voting.

If you suspect that the user is acting in bad faith, by all means flag for moderator attention, and we'll look into it. Travis J's advice regarding identifying plagiarism applies; using ideas is more of a grey area, but I trust that you'll know stolen code when you see it. Just remember that flagging doesn't guarantee we will take any sort of action against the user, if for example we deem their activity benign. It does guarantee that we'll keep a slightly closer eye on the user, especially if their activity continues to generate flags over time.

Answer (score 3):

The described situation is unethical in that it seems to provide worse solutions to problems as alternatives in order to achieve personal gain.

It is hard to determine if that is always the case, as all we have to go on is your description, but at the very least what is described is not desirable.

My main concern would be that often using slower methodology in order to create the same outcome causes content quality to drop. It would also be concerning to start seeing any of these approaches actually begin getting used in production.

There may be a case for plagiarism depending on how much content was changed. If there were 20 or 30 lines of code and only the loop condition of one line of code was changed then that would seem to pretty strongly indicate the rest of the code was plagiarized. Again, it is hard to say without concrete examples.

- If there is identifiable plagiarism, then custom flag the post with a link to the content which is indicated as being plagiarized from.
- If there is a pattern of almost plagiarism, then custom flag one of the posts with several links to other posts and explain the link and why you thought it was becoming a problem. Let the moderators or staff decide. Also, airing all of this out on meta if it turns out to not be plagiarism is undesirable for many reasons.
- If there is no plagiarism, but the content is in your expert opinion less performant than existing content, then downvote it and move on.